# How can I trigger an onchange event manually?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm setting a date-time textfield value via a calendar widget. Obviously, the calendar widget does something like this :

```
document.getElementById('datetimetext').value = date_value;
```

What I want is:
On changing value in the date-time textfield I need to reset some other fields in the page. I've added a `onchange` event listener to the `datetimetext` field which is not getting triggered, because I guess `onchange` gets triggered only when the element gets focus & its value is changed on losing focus.

Hence I'm looking for a way to manually trigger this `onchange` event (which I guess should take care of checking the value difference in the text field).

Any ideas?

Comment: $(document.activeElement).trigger("change");

Comment: $(<ELEMENT_SELECTOR>).change();

Comment: the second requires jquery

Answer (score 586, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do this. If the `onchange` listener is a function set via the `element.onchange` property and you're not bothered about the event object or bubbling/propagation, the easiest method is to just call that function:

```
element.onchange();
```

If you need it to simulate the real event in full, or if you set the event via the HTML attribute or `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`, you need to do a bit of feature detection to correctly fire the event:

```
if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else
    element.fireEvent("onchange");
```

Comment: thanks. this works, but am not sure about browser detection here. wondering if there is a way to do the same via YUI library. thanks anyways.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working in Android's WebView with those 3 lines from `else` block.

Comment: Andy E, this does not work in IE10, any ideas?

Comment: @NickBinnet: interesting.  I'm working in Linux at the moment and can't switch to test for a solution, but I would suggest swapping the `if` and `else` blocks, and testing for `if ('createEvent' in document)` instead.  Let me know if this works and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Andy, you are absolutely correct. It works. Could you please add a reference to this answer on the following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754972/correct-way-to-trigger-change-event-of-cascadingdropdown-using-jquery

Comment: I have a onchange event into a HTML element and `element.onchange();` worked

Comment: This will also work - $("#element").trigger('change'); // make sure you define onchange function above this call

Comment: I only see onchange() not work when using addEvent/attachEvent http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/s11uakx7/

Comment: its working great, but too damn slow, why is it? Can anything be done to boost performance of app?

Comment: this worked for me for an event defined in jQuery

Comment: @AndyE `Event.initEvent()` is deprecated. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) It is recomended to use the `Event()` constructor instead.

Comment: This is "The old-fashioned way". Now there is [another way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Creating_custom_events). See Milan answer.

Comment: "element.onchange is not a function" in latest chrome

Answer (score 653):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) suggests that there's a much cleaner way of doing this in modern browsers:

```
// Assuming we're listening for e.g. a 'change' event on `element`

// Create a new 'change' event
var event = new Event('change');

// Dispatch it.
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Are you sure that is not for custom events only?

Comment: @BrettZamir Worked for me (at least in Chrome 36) the following way: `document.querySelector('select.freight').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }))`

Comment: Just FYI on this... MDN does mention this, but its not supported by IE10+ (arguably also modern by definition of the word modern..) and only in the nightly of Safari (as time of writing)

IE10+ does have this constructor method but you need to specify the type of event, eg. MouseEvent or KeyboardEvent :see:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn905219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @MrJustastic A year later, MDN lists compatibility with MS Edge (the current version of IE, if you ask Microsoft) and Safari 6. On mobile, it lists iOS Safari 6, and I assume Chrome on Android ought to support it too.

Comment: This does not work on IE11

Comment: its working great, but too damn slow, why is it? Can anything be done to boost performance of app?

Comment: @Abhinav what is slow? Is it the method of dispatching itself or the handler code attached to the event?

Comment: @MilanIliev : I think the method of dispatching itself, because the handler code attached to the event executes fast when I use jquery's `trigger()` method. I dont want to use jquery since most part of my app is written in javascript. What can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: @Abhinav Not sure why this dispatch method would be slower. Can you provide examples of how you're attaching it in both cases (raw JS and jQuery) and also details on what browser(s) is it slow, and how slow?

Comment: @BrettZamir what does the 'bubbles' : true bit do?

Comment: @Rick : When an event "bubbles" in the DOM (like many built-in events), it means that unless a handler attached to the elements in the bubble chain (starting with the element on which an event is dispatched) stops propagation (as via a call to `event.stopPropagation()`), that element's parent will also be checked for event handlers to fire, with the process repeated until either propagation is stopped or there are no more ancestors (when one is at root). You can get this propagating behavior for events by adding `bubbles: true`.

Comment: Stopping propagation is different from `preventDefault` btw which stops default behaviors associated with an element from occurring, such as links being followed or forms being submitted, but it does not stop events being triggered on ancestors.

Comment: `element.dispatchEvent(new window.Event('change', { bubbles: true }))` if you want to bubble too

Comment: While using Chrome 80 in February 2020, the expression `document.createEvent('change')` gives me a runtime exception: "The provided event type ('change') is invalid.".

Comment: It's `new CustomEvent('change')` now(June 2020/Covid-19).

Comment: @MikeMestnik Actually the above code (`.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`) works just fine for me in FF.

Comment: Seriously, it's not as convenient as the .click() event? *facepalm* Trying to determine if dispatchEvent actually supports IE 10+ because it's important to be fully compatible.

Comment: `new Event('change')` is still valid according to MDN. It just doesn't allow for extra data to be sent?

Comment: @MikeMestnik , the prototype inheritance and property descriptors are different. May I ask, why not use "Event" but "CustomEvent" exactly? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795249/5113030 (*Event vs CustomEvent*...) ; https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents