# Javascript manually firing .onchange() event

Tags: javascript, input, onchange

I have an input field I want to assign a new value and fire an .onchange() event. I did the following:

```
document.getElementById("range").value='500';
document.getElementById("range").onchange();
```

Where range is my input Id.
I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

Is there a way to define the 'target'?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error about `target` is because there's code in the event handler that's trying to read the `target` property of the `Event` object associated with the change event. You could try passing in an faux-Event to fool it:

```
var range= document.getElementById('range');
range.onchange({target: range});
```

or, if you can, change the handler code to use `this` instead of `event.target`. Unless you are using delegation (catching change events on child object from a parent, something that is troublesome for change events because IE doesn't ‘bubble’ them), the target of the change event is always going to be the element the event handler was registered on, making `event.target` redundant.

If the event handler uses more properties of `Event` than just `target` you would need to fake more, or go for the ‘real’ browser interface to dispatching events. This will also be necessary if event listeners might be in use (`addEventListener`, or `attachEvent` in IE) as they won't be visible on the direct `onchange` property. This is browser-dependent (`fireEvent` for IE, `dispatchEvent` for standards) and not available on older or more obscure browsers.

Answer (score 9):

Try using [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423.aspx) or dispatchEvent (depending on browser) to raise the event:

```
document.getElementById("range").value='500';
if (document.getElementById("range").fireEvent) {
    document.getElementById("range").fireEvent("onclick");
} else if (document.getElementById("range").dispatchEvent) {
    var clickevent=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    clickevent.initEvent("click", true, true);
    document.getElementById("range").dispatchEvent(clickevent);
}
```

Comment: I think `fireEvent()` is an IE-only thing. Standards-compliant browsers use `dispatchEvent()`.

Comment: I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLInputElement> has no method 'fireEvent'" error with this

Comment: Update 2022: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent "[t]his feature [(Event.initEvent())] is no longer recommended". Use the Event instructor instead and then call dispatchEvent with that. Example and documentation see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Answer (score 3):

from : [http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg44887.html](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg44887.htmlreason?)

> Sometimes it's needed to create an
>   event programmatically. (Which is
>   different from running an event
>   function (triggering)
>
> This can be done by the following fire
>   code

```
> var el=document.getElementById("ID1")
> 
> fire(el,'change')
> 
> 
>    function fire(evttype) {
>        if (document.createEvent) {
>          var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
>          evt.initEvent( evttype, false, false);
>          el.dispatchEvent(evt);
>        } else if (document.createEventObject) {
>          el.fireEvent('on' + evttype);
>        }    } looks like this trick is not yet in jQuery, perhaps for a
> reason?
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, your code should work fine. There might be something else that's issuing the problem, though.

- Where do you run those two lines?
- Are you sure that the element with the
  `range` id is loaded by the time you
  run the code (e.g. you run it in
  document.ready).
- Are you sure that
  you only have *one* element with id
  `range` on the page?
- What is your `onchange()` function doing (could be
  helpful to post it here)?

Apart from that, I would recommend using jQuery (if possible):

```
$('#range').trigger('change');
```

or just

```
$('#range').change();
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

But as I mentioned, your case should work fine too: http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baeJr/)). Do you have any other code that may be the problem? How did you define your onchange handler?

Are you calling e.target in your onchange handler? I suspect this may be the issue... since you are doing the change programmatically, there is no corresponding window event.