# onchange event does not get fired on selenium type command

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am typing some value, on change do a total. But somehow, this event is not getting fired with selenium type command.

I also tried typeKey and typeAt ..But no success. Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 9):

To trigger the onchange event, try adding this command in Selenium IDE:

`fireEvent targetID blur`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (IMHO). This was *exactly* what I needed! Also, in my case, this had to be used with `sendKeys` rather than `type`. Thanks so much for this, @trex.

Answer (score 7):

Firefox has a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=566671) which prevents some events from being executed while the browser window is out of focus. This could be an issue when you're running your automation tests - which might be typing even if the window is out of focus.

To fix this issue I triggered the change event "manually", injecting javascript into my tests.:

```
//suppose "element" is an input field
element.sendKeys("value");
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change();", element);
```

As you might have noticed, I'm using jQuery to trigger the change event. If you're not using jQuery on your app, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually) how to trigger it using vanilla javascript.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Selenium 1.x, there is a fireEvent command that you can use to manually trigger the onChange event after typing in the value. Maybe that would solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution normally is found by looking at the JavaScript code..

An option you always have is to put in the value and manually trigger the actual OnChange event from code.

There are an open issue about this [link text](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=157)
Problem with FireFox Windows not being active and prevents the OnChange to be triggered.

Try this before using typeKeys command:

```
selenium.selectWindow(null);
```

Comment: I am using IDE. This is what i did. 
[ #Executing: |getEval | selenium.selectWindow(null) || ] Does not work. Error : selenium.selectWindow is not a function

Comment: I do normally only work with Selenium RC and I'm not sure its even possible to solve some of the issues with the IDE.. You should update your question with that info

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in IDE
do the following 3 commands in order

```
Typekeys   targetID    input
FireEvent  targetID    focus
Type       targetID    input
```

The source looks like this (input was letter `r`)

```
<tr>
<td>typeKeys</td>
<td>//form/input</td>
<td>r</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>fireEvent</td>
<td>//form/input</td>
<td>focus</td>
<tr>
<td>fireEvent</td>
<td>//form/input</td>
<td>focus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>//form/input</td>
<td>r</td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>//form/input</td>
<td>r</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "sendKeys" command was implemented to rectify this:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5451

This worked for me.

```
<tr>
    <td>sendKeys</td>
    <td>id=Quantity</td>
    <td>Type stuff here</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with a Dropdown list made with Ajax.

 As the user types in a field, the system displays AJAX `div`w with several options, each one as a link with `target='#'`

And even worse, there was a function called on the **onChange()** that filled a system flag, and that flag would be used as a validation on the form.submit()
(oh, the pain)

Anyways, my solution for this: 
1 - Selenium *sendKeys* command so the Ajax div would appear

```
<tr>
    <td>sendKeys</td>
    <td>id=txtTipoDocumento</td>
    <td>ipsum lorem</td>
</tr>
```

2 - wait for the link with the expected option to appear

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>link=ipsum lorem</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

3 - selenium *clickAt* the link

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>link=ipsum lorem</td>
    <td>10,20</td>
</tr>
```

4 - Here is the ONE of the catches: manually fire the *onChange()* AND *blur* events. Also, foce the browser to set focus on **different** field

```
 <tr>
        <td>fireEvent</td>
        <td>id=txtTipoDocumento</td>
        <td>blur</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fireEvent</td>
        <td>id=selSerie</td>
        <td>change()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fireEvent</td>
        <td>id=selSerie</td>
        <td>blur</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>focus</td>
        <td>id=imgDataElaboracao</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

5 - Finally, to be sure, I made Selenium do execute the ClickAt() command on the Submit button of the forme, **between a mouseDown and MouseUp commands**

```
<tr>
    <td>mouseDown</td>
    <td>id=btnSalvar</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>focus</td>
    <td>id=btnSalvar</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>id=btnSalvar</td>
    <td>10,20</td>
</tr>
```

Not elegant, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but able to resolve this issue. Below code is for enter text in input field and fire onchange event.

```
WebElement textBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
textBox.sendKeys("Test");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].onchange", 
  Arrays.asList(textBox));
```

Hope it will work!