# How can I send a Jquery trigger() command in Selenium IDE

Tags: jquery, selenium-ide

I have a `<select>` with a few `<option>`s that I am able to select in Selenium IDE with the `select` command.

```
<td>select</td>
<td>//div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/select</td>
<td>value=38</td>
```

Great.  (these are recipients for an internal email message)

But, apparently our website sends a `$("select").trigger("change")` when a user clicks an option from the drop-down list.  So even though I can select what I need, and have it show correctly on the page, when I try to send this message, I trip an error saying "you must select a recipient".  I asked our dev that builds the message form and he said once a user clicks a recipient, that click also sends a `$("select").trigger("change")` command.

I've tried this Selenium command:

```
<td>runScript</td>
<td>$("select").trigger("change")</td>
<td></td>
```

but it does nothing.  You can see what I'm trying to do here...  any ideas how to send this trigger?

Comment: Did you try using a click event to trigger this natively?

Comment: Alos look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689969/onchange-event-does-not-get-fired-on-selenium-type-command which suggest fireEvent.

Comment: Thanks @DMart.  I couldn't get a click event to work as this is from a Select2 dropdown list.  The select had aria-hidden=true on it, so I couldn't just click on it, and when I targeted the element with CSS or Xpath, it didn't fire any event triggers.

What finally was the solution for me was this:


`<td>fireEvent</td>`
`<td>//div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/select/</td>`
`<td>select2:select</td>`

I had to dig into the Select2 documentation to find the right event to trigger.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was trying to select an option from a Select2 dropdown list, here's the Selenium IDE command that worked for me:

```
<td>fireEvent</td>
<td>//div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/select/</td>
<td>select2:select</td>
```