# How to trigger an event in an input field changed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, input, dom-events

REWRITE:
I have a select field with an associated onchange event.

```
<select id='customer' onchange='loadRate(this.value)'>
```

At some point in my code, I assign a value to this select field with Javascript.

```
document.getElementById('customer').value = "Main St Packaging";
```

Why does this not trigger the `onchange` event? How do I fix it so that it does? Right now I am doing it by writing explicitly:

```
loadRate('Main St Packaging')
```

but I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Can you not just make one function that updates all of the fields at once?

Comment: Well there are a lot of fields. That's basically what I did to get around this, but it seems pretty inefficient.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's a duplicate, but the accepted answer seems relevant to your question: [Trigger onchange event manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/trigger-onchange-event-manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the "onchange" method explicitly:

```
var el = document.getElementById('customer');
el.value = "Main St Packaging";
el.onchange(); // Will run "loadRate(this.value)", per your HTML.
```

Comment: Thanks, JQuery for the win. I used $("#customer").change();

Comment: This throws an error "el.onchange is not a function", use `el.onchange = <yourFunctionName>` instead