# In Javascript, how to determine and call inherited listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, input, dom-events

If a `change` listener is attached to an item, it can be called with `item.onchange()`.  But what if the change trigger emanates from a parent node?

The context: use a `input` event to capture up/down changes on an INPUT type='number' item since `change` does *not* capture them.

Theory of operation: use `input` to capture, but wait 500 ms before calling normal `change` listeners.  Easy when the `change` listener is attached directly to the target element.  The problem is needed to call *inherited* change triggers as well - how do I know if any exist, and how do I call them?

**HTML:**

```
<form id='f'>
  <input type='number' id='i' />
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// attach main onchange trigger to form
document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('change',changeFunc,true);

// if user "scrolls" number value, do same as change trigger after 500 ms
var inputCt = 0;
function inputToChange(e) {
   inputCt++;
   setTimeout( next, 500 );
   function next() {
      inputCt--;
      if( !inputCt ) {
         // if element has it's own change trigger, call it
         if( e.target.onchange ) e.target.onchange(e);
         // PROBLEM - how to call inherited change triggers
      }
   }
}
document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('input',inputChange,true);
```

The only way I see to do this is to manually go through ancestors, checking for existence and calling as I go.  But that leads to the next problem: any one of these listener functions may have issued as `e.stopPropagation`, but I see now way of determining if this is indeed the case - which means climbing ancestors will not work.

---

as per @Andy E answer on [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/trigger-onchange-event-manually), here is the solution:

**Javascript:**

```
// attach main onchange trigger to form
document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('change',changeFunc,false);

// if user "scrolls" number value, do same as change trigger after 500 ms
var inputCt = 0;
function inputToChange(e) {
   inputCt++;
   setTimeout( next, 500 );
   function next() {
      inputCt--;
      if( inputCt ) return;
      var change = var change = document.createEvent("Event");
      change.initEvent('change',true,true);
      e.target.dispatchEvent(change);
   }
}
document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('input',inputChange,false);
```

note 1: that the `useCapture` (third) arg to `addEventListener` was wrong - needs to be false so item triggers are called before form triggers.

note 2: this function would probably be better suited to 'click' than 'input' - the problem with 'click' is that focus and text positioning clicks need to be distinguished from click changing the value.

Comment: " how do I know if any exit"  do you MEAN EXIT or do you MEAN EXIST? quite different in this context.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss - "exist" - thanks

Comment: You are dealing with events.  You should NOT need to "call" events on ancesters, they should have event handlers to "handle" the events, although you MIGHT consider "triggering" those events - the stopPropagation is there for some reason by the author of that event, thus I would foresee the trigger of "new" events approriate for the parent elements to handle, although here I would prefer to see the event bubble and refactor that event propagation.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss - I think we are going in circles a little.  do you know how to create a chat for us - that is, if you would be kind enough to take the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @Andy E in answer to [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/trigger-onchange-event-manually), build an event and dispatch.  have put details in the question.

btw, `onchange` is set *if and only if* the `change` trigger was set through an `onchange` attribute, *not* with `addEventListener('change',...)`

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, `$(e.target).change()` should do the job, I believe. Or `$(e.target).trigger(eventname)`, with `eventname = 'change'` in your case, and any other event name in general.

Apparently, `change` event is valid only on `input`s, `textarea`s and `select`s, which cannot be nested. So you cannot have a problem when parent defines change event handler that needs to be triggered after the child's one.

Comment: using javascript - open jQuery source and copy the way they trigger events. why on earth not use jQuery?

Comment: Although `change` event is not valid at the FORM level, it can be _applied_ at the form level, and then all ITEMs in the form will use it

Comment: personally I am very comfortable with js as a language and with it's level of abstraction.  personally do not care for jQuery's hiding functionality from me, nor do I find its notation aesthetically pleasing.  I realize this is a minority report probably only favored by other graybeards as myself.

Comment: ok, do not use jQuery. just look at how they trigger events and steal it.

Comment: and if you do not like using jQuery, do not use it anywhere - all your scripts will still work. use it just in this particular case to ease your life. why not?

Comment: what I am working on is a library with no outside dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In the event listener, create reference to `this` object (for example, `var that = this;`). Then, you can use `that.onchange(e);` in the `next`'s body.

Comment: am not understanding you at all.  to the best of my knowledge, `this` in an event is the `window`.

Comment: @cc young It is not. If you use `addEventListener`, the `this` object in the event handler refers to the element which "owns" the handler (`document.getElementById('f')` in your case).

Comment: in this case the handler function is part of the Render class.  within the function, `this` references that class, not `document.getElementById('f')`

Answer (score 0):

A change even will not fire on "up/down" I make the assumption you mean arrow up/down?

If that is the case, you will need to capture the key event (key press, key up, key down etc) for those KEY events.

Comment: for example, in chrome <input type='number' .../>, the input box has up/down arrows to the right - clicking on these increments/decrements the value.  could use `click` to capture the activity, but it seems the problem remains the same.

Comment: See my note on the question regarding events, event triggers etc.

Comment: FYI, IF you have the desire to not use a library, you might want to start with a reference page for events such as: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Comment: appreciate the reference to quirksmode - that page and I are very good friends.  recently found http://help.dottoro.com/lagstsiq.php/#Event which has been a great reference.  what I'm working on is a library that has no outside dependencies.