# In a Javascript event, how to determine stopPropagation() has been called?

Tags: javascript, triggers, dom-events

If `e.preventDefault()` is called, can see reflected in `e.defaultPrevented` method.

Is there a similar property for `e.stopPropagation()`?  If not, how to determine?

Comment: Step No. 1: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#webidl-events-Event

Comment: so you're saying that if the event is in `CAPTURING PHASE` then `stopPropagation()` has been called?

Comment: @young No, that's unrelated... I'm not even sure that all browsers do implement capturing phases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't looked through jQuery to see their method, but it seems you could override the `stopPropagation` method on the base `Event` object, set a flag, and then call the overridden method.

Something like:

```
var overriddenStop =  Event.prototype.stopPropagation;
Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function(){
    this.isPropagationStopped = true;
    overriddenStop.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a [bad idea](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Comment: you're probably right.  very sneaky way of implementing so it's invisible downstream.  this might work!  need to attack in the morning when my brain works.

Comment: @Šime - I agree. I suppose this felt like less of an "extension" since it is not adding new methods to the Event class, albiet instance variables. So would you agree that the best method here would be to make an event object wrapper?

Comment: @Josiah Well, not make one personally `:)` I don't want to waste my time with such low-level things. There are enough event libraries out there...

Comment: although Extending the DOM is generally a bad idea, @Josiah's solution does not universally extend the DOM's Event, but rather let's me extend particular Event instances in a well defined fashion.  the big win is that it lets users keep their existent trigger scripts unchanged.  it appears to have no nasty side effects.

Comment: This helped me to debug where in the code an event was stopped bubbling. Turn out to be bootstrap :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't.

I can tell, because jQuery's `isPropagationStopped()` method doesn't use any browser API internally, but instead implements this feature manually. (If there were such a feature in the browsers - built-in - jQuery would use it instead of doing it manually.)

So, in jQuery, a new event object will get this property (inherited):

```
isPropagationStopped: returnFalse
```

and then, when you invoke `stopPropagation()` on that event object, jQuery will manually alter this property:

```
stopPropagation: function() {
    this.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;
    ...
}
```

`returnFalse` and `returnTrue` are functions which return `false` and `true` respectively.

Comment: wow, thanks for looking a jQuery code - I really felt that was what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you can check the property `e.cancelBubble` to check for native stops. Other browsers do not have this functionality.

However, you could just keep track of it yourself. Because of the nature of it, you wouldn't be able to check it anywhere, except in the same handler that stops the propagation itself (the event won't bubble up, more handlers won't get called), so I can't imagine a situation where it would be necessary. What are you trying to do?

Edit: I thought you were using jQuery at first. For those who are:
You can use the `e.isPropagationStopped()` method, which will check if propagation has been stopped from jQuery. If propogation is stopped natively, this won't be able to tell.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257581/in-javascript-how-to-determine-and-call-inherited-listeners for context.  essentially `change` is not being called and need to initiate it myself

Comment: if you look at the link, by using `dispatchEvent()` - you're right - this issue is no longer in play

Comment: I see. Events still bubble correctly when you trigger them manually, so they should obey `.stopPropagation()` already.