# Select element not returning webelement from .first_selected_option() method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently experiencing some difficulties writing a method that will allow me to find the value of the currently selected option within a Select element.

```
<select id="select_foo_bar">
   <option value="0">FOO</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">BAR</option>
   <option value ="2">FOOBAR</option>
</select>
```

Currently I have this:

```
def find_selected_option(self):
    self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_location((By.ID, "select_foo_bar"))
    option = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("select_foo_bar")).first_selected_option()
    return option.get_attribute("value")
```

As I understand it, that method will find the `option` element, get the `value` and return it.

Unfortunately, I'm receiving the error `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable`. This is occurring on the `option = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("select_foo_bar")).first_selected_option()` line. It doesn't even reach the point of the `return` statement.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by breaking down the line starting `option = `, so you first find the `<select>` as a WebElement, then (on a new line) cast to Select, and only then try and call the first_selected_option method?

Comment: Hi @vincebowdren, I probably should have mentioned before that I have stepped through, broken it down into local variables a number of times.

Whilst stepping through, it successfully reaches the .first_selected_option() method from the Select class. It does proceed through the loop and returns the second option, as I would expect. Yet it is after that point that I receive the error detailed above.

Comment: When you've first found the `<select>` as a WebElement, can you call methods on it then? Or is it only after you've cast it to a `Select` that the method call fails?

Comment: It finds the element fine, casts it fine and loops through the options to find the 'selected' option. At that point it appears to return that `WebElement` but it blows up after its found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue. It was due to me reading the docs with tired eyes yesterday.

The call is needed was `first_selected_option` and not `first_selected_option()`

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the `option = Select(...` line?

Perhaps this is what you are looking for: [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

`self.driver.find_element_by_id("select_foo_bar")` should already return the element, can you just call `self.driver.find_element_by_id("select_foo_bar").first_selected_option()`?

Comment: Ah good spot but unfortunately that was just my angry typing. Edited.