# How to Select Items in Dropdown in Selenium

Tags: python, select, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Firstly, I have been trying to get the dropdown from this web page: http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Interconnect/Home/Products/ProductCatalog/Catalog/?PC_Z7_RJH9U5230O73D0ISNF9B3C3SI1000000_nid=RFCNF5FK7WitWK7G49LP38glNZJXPCDXLDbl

This is the code I have:

```
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    from pprint import pprint

    from selenium import webdriver

    url = 'http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Interconnect/Home/Products/ProductCatalog/Catalog/?PC_Z7_RJH9U5230O73D0ISNF9B3C3SI1000000_nid=RFCNF5FK7WitWK7G49LP38glNZJXPCDXLDbl'

    element_xpath = '//*[@id="Component1"]'
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
    element_xpath = '/option[@value="02"]'
    all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for option in all_options:
        print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
        option.click()
    source = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    driver.quit()

    source = str(source)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

    print soup
```

What prints out is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../../../test.py", line 58, in <module>
Value is: XX
    main()
  File "../../../../test.py", line 46, in main
    option.click()
  File "/home/eric/dev/octocrawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 54, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/eric/dev/octocrawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 228, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/eric/dev/octocrawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/eric/dev/octocrawler-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 158, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'{"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:51413","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"sessionId\\": \\"30e4fd50-f0e4-11e3-8685-6983e831d856\\", \\"id\\": \\":wdc:1402434863875\\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/30e4fd50-f0e4-11e3-8685-6983e831d856/element/%3Awdc%3A1402434863875/click"}}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

And the weirdest most infuriating bit of it all is that sometimes it actually all works out. I have no clue what's going on here.

---

**UPDATE**

It seems I have no issues with visibility of dropdown forms on other sites, just this one. Is there something that might make the form invisible (and if so, why only 95% of the time)? Could there be an issue loading the page that might cause things not to be visible?

Comment: I noticed you are using PhantomJS. First thing I would try: does this work in a real browser?

Comment: It did the same thing in Firefox to no real success (it still failed 90% of the time on un-changing code).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Answer (score 5):

Using Selenium Webdriver with Python3 here's how I did it:

```
    all_options = self.driver.find_element_by_id("Component1")
    options = all_options.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for each_option in all_options:
        print(each_option.get_attribute("value"))
```

If you're trying to select something from the textbox here's how to do it:

```
    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("Component1"))
    select.select_by_visible_text("02")
```

references: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html

Comment: There is no problem with printing each options. It always works.
On the other hand, if I try selecting, that works without exception 5-10% of the time (that's if the code doesn't change, too).

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID "Component1")))
select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver:Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Component1")))
select.select_by_visible_text("Text to look for")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath like this:
Find element using below xpath and click on it.
Xpath: `//select[@id='Component1']/option[text()='04']`

If the above code does not work then, first click on dropdown using:

xpath: `//select[@id='Component1']`
then click on option.

Comment: in drop down there is @value not text()