# selenium drop down options and usgs webportal

Tags: php, jquery, python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I was following the guide below, to click on africa west under the regions drop down menu using...

[Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(usgs_dataportal_ppt)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='regionCombobox']    /option[text()='af-w']").click()
```

I have also tried sending keys looking at different containers other than regioncombobox to see if i can change the values to africa west.

the website is http://earlywarning.usgs.gov/adds/downloads/index.php

However I keep getting an error that selenium cannot find the element.

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='regionCombobox']/option[text()='af-w']"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the dropdown button and [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the link with `Africa - West` text to appear:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://earlywarning.usgs.gov/adds/downloads/index.php')

# explicitly wait for button to appear
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.custom-combobox > a")))
button.click()

# explicitly wait for "Africa - West" link to appear
africa_west = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Africa - West")))
africa_west.click()
```

---

Here is how you can get and click all the dropdown buttons:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.custom-combobox > a")))

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.custom-combobox > a')

# region
buttons[0].click()

# product
buttons[1].click()

# period
buttons[2].click()
```

Comment: When I did that I got  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
 selector","selector":"span.custom-combobox > a"}

Comment: @BaconDoggie I think we should wait for button to appear also - updated the code, check it out.

Comment: I am new to selenium and just wanted to ask you how come i needed to use css selector custom box instead of the combobox and then wait 10 seconds? Also Thank you so much, you helped me out.

Comment: @BaconDoggie you are welcome. The problem is that you cannot use `Select` class here and manipulate select->option construction because an actual `select` element is invisible. The dropdown you see on the screen is actually a span element with an a element as a "V" button on the right. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me, it sorta makes sense. I will apply the same process to the other buttons so I can auto download these files.

Comment: If I could bother you with one more question, it looks like whenever i use the code you gave me above i notice that it clicks through all the options that have custom-combobox as the class when you first run it. I wanted to know how I could distinguish between each combobox so that I click on the other buttons (which are also custom comboboxes)

Comment: @BaconDoggie there are different ways to do it. The simplest is to refer to each button by index - first is region, second is product, third is period.

Comment: this will sound dumb but my first insinct was to try button[0].click(), but i guess that was not it

Comment: @BaconDoggie I've updated an answer and provided a sample code to click dropdown buttons, give it a try.