# Select dropdown in AngularJS application from Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, protractor

I wanted to test page in `Python` `Selenium`, which uses `AngularJS`. It contains a select option and I have tried a number of options to select it but it fails.

```html
<select id="xtzpp001" ng-model="..." ng-options="...." ng-change="changeView()">
  <option value class>select</option>
  <option value="200" selected="selected">Student 1</option>
  <option value="201">Student 2</option>
  <option value="202">Student 3</option>
</select>
```

As I said, I tried---

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="xtzpp001"]/option[contains(text(), "Student 2")]').click()
```

then

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('xtzpp001'))
for i in select.options:
   .......etc etc
```

I used explicit waits also.

I came to know that pytractor can help me in this situation (not being actively developed though), but I am unable to find any documentation regarding select option using pytractor.

Is there any other way to achieve this?? or pytractor equivalent?

Or can I use protractor(or any javascript framework) to continue in testing in `Javascript` from this stage and integrate/callback the results in `Python`??

Comment: I am ready to re-do everything in Javascript using Selenium if it is possible to automate AngularJS page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can also use Actions to click the menu item, here is an example:

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav #submenu1")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden_submenu).perform()
```

Comment: how did you come up with 'submenu1' and 'nav'??

Answer (score 0):

Use the Select class from selenium.webdriver.support.ui. Pass the select webelement to the constructor. Use selectByVisibleText. Refer to the answer by @alecxe in the post - [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: I have alreay tried those options, including select_by_index(), select_by_value() from http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select

Comment: What error are you getting? Or what is happening on the browser?

Comment: throws NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the possible attempt but never got success, you should try using `execute_script()` as below :-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("xtzpp001")

driver.execute_script("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", element, "Student 2");
```