# How to select a value from a drop-down using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, select, xpath

I want to select an option from a select field using Selenium & Python.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<select autocomplete="off" class="style_input_item" name="AccountEnable" id="Enable" value="0" onchange="onPageDataChange()">
    <option value="0" selected="selected"><script>T("Disabled")</script>Disabled</option>
    <option value="1"><script>T("Enabled")</script>Enabled</option>
</select>
```

And I tried as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Enable"]/option[value="1"]').click()
```

I received that error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="Enable"]/option[value="0"]"}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value). The accepted answer isn't the best way.The best way is alecxe's answer. See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't the best way.The best way is alecxe's answer. See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Enable"]/option[@value="1"]').click()
```

or

```
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Enable"]/option[2]').click()
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you include Select:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

then

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Enable'))
select.select_by_index(0)
```