# selenium web driver accessing list box values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5

I am facing problem with Selenium web driver in accessing List box Values.

Check the image:
[image]

[image]

I am able to paste value and pass the class name of list which i want to select, basically i  have to select every time the very first option which is displayed in the list

```
 1   driver.get('https://my.maerskline.com/schedules/vessel')
 2   button = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_b-vesselCode")   
 3   button.click()        
 4   button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_autogen1_search")
 5   button1.send_keys(Vessel_name)        
 6   button3 = driver.find_element_by_id("select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable")
 7   button3.click()
 8   button2 = driver.find_element_by_id("schedulesByVesselSearchButton")
    button2.click()
```

Line 6 gives me below error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"id","selector":"select2-results-dept-0 select2-result
select2-result-selectable"}   (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)  
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Any idea how I can get this done? Any more information needed let me know.  Thanks

updated Code

```
if Vessel_name != "":
        #driver.get('https://my.maerskline.com/vessels?searchTerm={0}'.format(Vessel_name))
        print(Vessel_name)

        driver.get('https://my.maerskline.com/schedules/vessel')
        button = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_b-vesselCode")   
        button.click()        
        button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_autogen1_search")
        button1.send_keys(Vessel_name)       
        button3 =driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#select2-results-1>li:nth-child(1)")
        button3.click()
        #button2 = driver.find_element_by_id("schedulesByVesselSearchButton")
        #button2.click()
        try:



        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be locating the element by its class name. The element in the image you provided does not have any id.

Give this xpath a go:

```
//ul[@id='select2-results-1']/li[@‌​class='selec‌​t2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted']
```

If you are sure you always want to select the first `li`, you can make the xpath alot tidier by referencing its index:

```
(//ul[@id='select2-results-1']/li)[1]
```

Comment: apologies - i am searchig by class name only and the error is

Comment: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: If there is more then one class name assigned to an element, you cannot use the collection of class names in selenium. this is known as a compound class name. So you need to be more specific with your locator. xpath or css would be a better fit here.

Comment: cool, if you get stuck..post your attempt here and ill help out.

Comment: button3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='select2-drop']/ul[@id='select2-results-1']/li[@class='select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted']")

Comment: we have div with id select2-drop and then <ul> and finannly <li>

Comment: Error - unable to locate element :(

Comment: first normal code is giving me same error, but second code is not giving error ,it is not helping in clicking the vessel name though, it is unable to click on search button...and error is - Message: unknown error: Element <input id="schedulesByVesselSearchButton"

Answer (score 0):

as this is drop down with value you should user select class to identify the web-element

you can refer below link to solve this issue :-

[Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: Can we ? i dont think so because in my HTML there is no option or select tag used its only <li>

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `find_element_by_id` but giving class name. You should use `element_by_css_selector("#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(2)")` for second option.

```
"#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(1)" >> MAJESTIC   
"#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(2)" >> MAJESTC MAERSK   
"#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(3)" >> NORTHERN MAJESTC
```

Check the following

```
driver.get('https://my.maerskline.com/schedules/vessel')
button = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_b-vesselCode")   
button.click()        
button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_autogen1_search")
button1.send_keys(Vessel_name)        
button3 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(2)")
button3.click()
button2 = driver.find_element_by_id("schedulesByVesselSearchButton")
button2.click()
```

check this code works:

```
>>> driver.button = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_b-vesselCode")
>>> button = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_b-vesselCode")
>>> button.click()
>>> button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("s2id_autogen1_search")
>>> button1.send_keys(Vessel_name)
>>> button1.send_keys("majestic")
>>> button3 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(2)")
>>> button3.click()
>>> button2 = driver.find_element_by_id("schedulesByVesselSearchButton")
>>> button2.click()
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".muted.scheduleVesselHeader").text
u'Port Terminal Arrival Voyage Departure'
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tbody > tr:nth-child(2)").text
u'Rotterdam\nAPM 2 Terminal Maasvlakte II 15 Jan 2017, 06:00 649W | 649W 17 Jan 2017, 05:00'
```

Comment: apologies - i am searchig by class name only and the error is – Er Gaurav Chhabra 52 mins ago   
     
Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: now i am trying to use xpath because there is no other way around

Comment: did you try the answer?

Comment: i did try  on class and id getting same error - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: also if i pass this argument in html we have more than one class with same name,isn't that create a problem here

Comment: @ErGauravChhabra css should be unique. check the updated answer: `"#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(2)"`

Comment: same error again, is there anything in html which allow the tags to be hidden even though they are present ?

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#select2-results-1 > li:nth-child(1)"}

Comment: after searching same example online i removed spaced between class name and li now its running without error but its not selecting list value ... why this is hapening

Comment: @ErGauravChhabra added shell output. It works. Hope you accept the answer.