# Python Selenium check select all in checkbox input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to check the `(SELECT ALL)` checkbox from the input dropdown menu. How could I do that? Here is the screenshot of the dropdown menu. The field's id next to the dropdown icon is `rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl00`.

[image]

So far here is my code, but gave me no good result.

```
checkboxes = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl00']")
for checkbox in checkboxes:
    if not checkbox.is_selected():
        checkbox.click()
```

Another try, but still no good result.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl00']").click()
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks and regards,

Arnold

**EDIT**

If I try to inspect the element of the field, here is the HMTL code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl00" name="rvrMain$ctl00$ctl09$ctl03$ctl00" onclick="MVClassrvrMain_ctl00_ctl09.SetAutoPostBackOnHide();MultiValidValuesSelectAll(this, 'rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03');" type="checkbox"><label for="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl00">(Select All)</label></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl01" name="rvrMain$ctl00$ctl09$ctl03$ctl01" onclick="MVClassrvrMain_ctl00_ctl09.SetAutoPostBackOnHide();OnClickMultiValidValue(this, document.getElementById('rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl00'));" type="checkbox"><label for="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl01">148950&nbsp;-&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;CATUR&nbsp;SENTOSA&nbsp;ADIPRANA&nbsp;-&nbsp;KOTABUMI</label></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl02" name="rvrMain$ctl00$ctl09$ctl03$ctl02" onclick="MVClassrvrMain_ctl00_ctl09.SetAutoPostBackOnHide();OnClickMultiValidValue(this, document.getElementById('rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl00'));" type="checkbox"><label for="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl02">148961&nbsp;-&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;CATUR&nbsp;SENTOSA&nbsp;ADIPRANA&nbsp;-&nbsp;BANDAR&nbsp;LAMPUNG</label></span></td>
      </tr>
      --- the list keeps go on and on---
      <tr>
         <td nowrap="nowrap"><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl203" name="rvrMain$ctl00$ctl09$ctl03$ctl203" onclick="MVClassrvrMain_ctl00_ctl09.SetAutoPostBackOnHide();OnClickMultiValidValue(this, document.getElementById('rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl00'));" type="checkbox"><label for="rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl203">320864&nbsp;-&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;LIQUID&nbsp;KENCANA&nbsp;ABADI&nbsp;-&nbsp;NIAS</label></span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select the checkbox with label `(Select All)`.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Dillanm, I revised my code and it worked. Basically I have to click on the dropdown menu icon first, and then click on the one of the checkboxes. So here is the code:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl01').click() # this one click on the dropdown menu icon
browser.find_element_by_id('rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl00').click() # this one click on the checkbox, either uncheck or check
```

Comment: Can you share `HTML` of pop-up?

Comment: have you performing click on  the down arrow button of dropdown before moving to checkbox ?

Comment: You could try the Select class from the WebDriver Support package; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28613320/3110529) answer for more details (not sure if it will work with checkboxes though)

Comment: @NarendraRajput No I have not. I will try your suggestion, by clicking the dropdown icon first then move to the checkbox. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Dillanm Thanks for the link. I will also give it a try. Will come back to you guys soon.

Comment: @Dillanm thanks mate! Yes you are right. I have to click on the icon first and followed by click the checkbox. Now I can check the `(Select All)` checkbox! How can I mark that your comment is the right answer?

Comment: @arnold Are you sure this solved the issue, could you show us the code which fixed it?

Comment: @Dillanm sorry for my tardy reply. Please see the updated post. I added my final code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you are missing the step to click on the `down arrow icon` of your element So Just click the down arrows, the dropdown items get visible and then have to perform your check option.

Like -

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(down_arrow_icon_xpath).click()
checkbox = browser.find_element_by_id("rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl03_ctl00")
    if not checkbox.is_selected():
        checkbox.click()
```

Comment: First line will cause error as you're trying to click on list (use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`). Also second line will return `0` elements as there is no `input` fields with `id='rvrMain_ctl00_ctl09_ctl00'` in provided `HTML` code (but this seem to be OP misleading). As target check-box is initially known there is no need to loop through all the options, you can just use `"(Select All)"` to check exact

Comment: @Andersson, you are right , The problem was he missed to click on down arrow icon . So i did mentioned that and pasted the code in hurry . Thanks for remind :)