# Select a value from a ajax drop down

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to mimic selecting a value from an ajax dropdown value using selenium and python. I am not sure how to approach this.

This is how the text box works - I enter in the value, it searches for it and appears at the bottom of the text box as an ajax drop down. How can I select that using selenium and python?

Here is the highlighted html code for that field

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: this is a ajax drop box.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't seem to show the code for the drop down itself. Could you include that, preferably as text? If the dynamic drop down renders as a select element, then the link @downshift provided is relevant. If it renders as divs/spans/etc then it'll be different, and it'll depend on the HTML rendered.