# How to extract option from "<div class='ui-helper-hidden-accessible'>" by selenium driver?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I want to use selenium and python to crawl this site : https://ntrl.ntis.gov/NTRL

However when i want to change the year of drop-down list, it can't work.

Here are its HTML:

```
<div id="advSearchForm:FromYear" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="min-width: 63px;">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input id="advSearchForm:FromYear_focus" name="advSearchForm:FromYear_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" readonly="readonly" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="advSearchForm:FromYear_items" aria-activedescendant="advSearchForm:FromYear_0" aria-describedby="advSearchForm:FromYear_0" aria-disabled="false">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <select id="advSearchForm:FromYear_input" name="advSearchForm:FromYear_input" tabindex="-1">
            <option value="*" selected="selected">&lt;1900</option>
            <option value="1900">1900</option>
            <option value="1901">1901</option>
            <option value="1902">1902</option>
            <option value="1903">1903</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label id="advSearchForm:FromYear_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">&lt;1900</label>
    <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are my code:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='advSearchForm:FromYear']/div[2]/select"))
select.select_by_value("1902")
```

But it get exception:

```
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

I tried to use js script:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('advSearchForm:FromYear_input').options[2].selected = 'true'")
```

But it also don't work,I test that `select.select_by_value(xxx)` can be used on other drop-down list, so it may be the trouble of `<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">`, so how can i deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `click` event to click on the element (the `Select` element with the id of "advSearchForm:FromYear_input") first, then the [ExplicitWait event](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait until the element is visible, then you should be able to change the year using the `select_by_value` method.

Also I would steer away from using XPath and use a [CSS selector](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) instead, even better would be to create a [Page Object Model](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) to reduce the work required to keep your tool working in the future should the page be updated.

Sorry that I cannot be much more help, I am not that familiar with python.

You could also refer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

**Edit**

It looks like that are using the `option` items inside the `select` as the master list and the actual selection takes place inside another element further down the page. This element is dynamically built in Javascript, so my suggestion in the comments will not work.

I have hacked together a working application in C# to give you an idea of what you need to do:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ':' has a special meaning in CSS selectors so we need to escape it using \\
    const string dropdownButtonSelector = "div#advSearchForm\\:datePublPanel div.ui-selectonemenu-trigger";
    // {0} is a placeholder which is used to insert text during runtime
    const string dynamicallyBuiltListItemSelectorTemplate = "ul#advSearchForm\\:FromYear_items li[data-label=\"{0}\"]";
    // Rather than being a constant this value will be determined at runtime
    const string valueToSelect = "1902";

    // Setup driver and wait
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    // Load page
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://ntrl.ntis.gov/NTRL/");
    // Wait until the first (index 0) dropdown list button inside the publication date dive is deemed "clickable"
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(dropdownButtonSelector)[0]));

    Console.WriteLine("Element is visible");

    // Open the dropdown list
    driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(dropdownButtonSelector)[0].Click();

    Console.WriteLine("Dropdown should be open");

    // Select the element from the dynamic Javascript built list
    string desiredValueListItemSelector = string.Format(dynamicallyBuiltListItemSelectorTemplate, valueToSelect);
    driver.FindElementByCssSelector(desiredValueListItemSelector).Click();

    Console.WriteLine($"Selected value {valueToSelect} using selector: {desiredValueListItemSelector}");
    Console.ReadLine();

    driver.Close();
}
```

==========================================================================

**Edit2**

Include python answer, I have never written python before but this appears to work. I would strongly suggest looking at some of the links I posted above about using the PageObject model and Explicit waits, as well as avoiding the use of XPATH selectors though.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

# Set the year to select
fromYearToSelect = "1902"

# Create the driver and load the page
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ntrl.ntis.gov/NTRL/")

# Find and click the "From" dropdown elems[1] is the "To" dropdown
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#advSearchForm\\:datePublPanel div.ui-selectonemenu-trigger")
elems[0].click()

# Select the year
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#advSearchForm\\:FromYear_items li[data-label='{0}']".format(fromYearToSelect)).click()

# Wait to see the results (we should be using an Explicit Wait  here)
sleep(2)

# Close the driver
driver.close()
```

Comment: I tried to click (element with the id of "advSearchForm:FromYear_input), but it resport "Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"

Comment: @SPX-4800 It looks like you will need to click on the arrow element to the right of the `Select` elements content first. You can do this by: `driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('div[data-widget=\"widget_advSearchForm_datePublPane\l"] div.ui-selectonemenu-trigger')[0].click()");` You might have to reconcile the double quotes inside the `execute_script` function. I have tried to escape them but I am not sure if that will work in Python.

Comment: @SPX-4800 I have edited my original answer above to include a working `C#` snippet which you should be able to translate into Python. Can you let me know whether or not this manages to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for help, I finally solved it by this way: I click this element first:‘.//div[@id='advSearchForm:FromYear']/div[3]’, and then wait for drop-down appears, finally i click the year option like '1902'

Comment: Glad to hear it @SPX-4800. Would you mind accepting the answer. :-)

Comment: Sorry, i think your answer is not accurate enough, and i am not familiar with C#, so i can't except it.But thanks for your help

Comment: @SPX-4800 I have edited my answer to include python.