# How to select 'All' from dropdown using Selenium/Pyautogui on Python

Tags: python, selenium

How to select 'All' from dropdown using Selenium/Pyautogui on Python

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
scrolldown = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 
document.body.scrollHeight);")
displayall = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.k-icon.k-i-arrow-
s').click()
x,y = pyautogui.position()
z = y+25
movemouse = pyautogui.moveTo(x,z, duration=0.25)
movemousepos = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.click()
```

HTML:

```
<span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" 
unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" 
aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" style="" aria-
activedescendant="36e1dea4-df6d-4f58-afd5-77d93c0f7251">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-input">All</span>
<span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
</span></span>
<select data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
<option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
<option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option>
<option value="50">50</option></select></span>
```

There are no errors but it is not working. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I dont get which drop down value you wanted category or subcategory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: Look at @alecxe answer, not the accepted answer.

Comment: @iamsankalp89 i would like to get the dropdown value 'All' . It is the dropdown beside 'items per page' on the webpage

Comment: @guy I have tried alecxe's method. I received error that the element is not visible. is there a way to make the element visible?

Comment: You want to select all value right??

Comment: @iamsankalp89 yes!

Comment: Can i give you code in JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know selenium python throughly, so I have given you code of JAVA. Convert it into Python. As I have seen the HTML it is quite difficult to select value from dropdown so that you can used `JavascriptExecutor`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/software and tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.thaibma.or.th/EN/News/Search.aspx");
WebElement ItemsPerPage= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='k-icon k-i-arrow-s']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", ItemsPerPage);
WebElement AllItem= driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //li[contains(@role,'option')][contains(text(),'All')]"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", AllItem);
```

Comment: I have convert  to python. It works! Thanks so much!