# Find element by value Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using Selenium with Python to automaticlly extract some data from our power plants and right now I need to click on an element.
The problem is that the element's `xpaths` and order change for each plant we are monitoring. The only static info is the `value`, just like in the 3rd line `value="T_U0`.

I tried many approaches and I couldn't find a solution. I can't use index or child because the order of the parameters is changing. I tried CSS selector with no success.

Here you get some of my tries...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='T_U0']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[@data-id-sys-abbreviation='388']").click()
```

I tried many other things but I was just desperately trying anything.

**What I really need is a `find_by_value`, if there is a way of doing it please let me know, if there isn't please show me how I can do it.**

[I need to click in some options that change order accordingly to the plant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJugX.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. just copy paste it in and use the code format button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: @Jacobr365 can I copy the HTML from Chrome? bc I tried and I could copy only one line at a time and it got all messed up

Comment: Yes you can. in the inspect box select elements tab, then click on a block and right click copy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is with the first xpath. You are trying to locate an input while you need to get option.

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='T_U0']").click()
```

Comment: It did work! Thank you Anand, it was so simple and I couldn't see it, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to click/select element via displayed text. 
Pseudo code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[text()="Some text"]").click()
```