# Dropdown with classname not working with select function Selenium

Tags: selenium, select, xpath, drop-down-menu

I have a path:

```
<div class="jss601 jss602 jss581" aria-pressed="false" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" xpath="1"><span></span></div>
```

but I could not write the XPath or CSS for clicking the element. Could you please help me?

This is a dropdown list called as "Tip" how can I manage the selection because it is not a select so I could not use the select function:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="MuiList-root-139 MuiList-padding-140" role="listbox" xpath="1">
    <li tabindex="-1" class="MuiButtonBase-root-55 MuiListItem-root-143 MuiListItem-default-146 MuiListItem-gutters-150 MuiListItem-button-151 MuiMenuItem-root-296" role="option" data-value="">Hiçbiri
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="MuiButtonBase-root-55 MuiListItem-root-143 MuiListItem-default-146 MuiListItem-gutters-150 MuiListItem-button-151 MuiMenuItem-root-296" role="option" data-value="RTU">RTU
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-55 MuiListItem-root-143 MuiListItem-default-146 MuiListItem-gutters-150 MuiListItem-button-151 MuiMenuItem-root-296 MuiMenuItem-selected-297" role="option" data-value="Substation Control System">Substation Control System
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="MuiButtonBase-root-55 MuiListItem-root-143 MuiListItem-default-146 MuiListItem-gutters-150 MuiListItem-button-151 MuiMenuItem-root-296" role="option" data-value="Control Center">Control Center
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="MuiButtonBase-root-55 MuiListItem-root-143 MuiListItem-default-146 MuiListItem-gutters-150 MuiListItem-button-151 MuiMenuItem-root-296" role="option" data-value="IED">IED
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<li tabindex="-1" class="MuiButtonBase-root-55 MuiListItem-root-143 MuiListItem-default-146 MuiListItem-gutters-150 MuiListItem-button-151 MuiMenuItem-root-296" role="option" data-value="RTU" xpath="1">RTU
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: How is the `<div>` related to `<ul>` and `<li>`? Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a dropdown example and how find a element in this dropdown.

[Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: No it is not a solution

Comment: It's a good example to study and understand how the Selenium works. I read this and helped me ;)