# Selenium Select2 Dropdown Menu's - Cannot locate element

Tags: selenium, web, testing, automated-tests, jquery-select2

I'm having an issue where I cannot select the ID or items in the select2 drop-down menus using Selenium.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='propertymanagementtype']/option[text()='Managed let']").click()
```

HTML code

```
<select name="propertymanagementtype" id="propertymanagementtype">
   <option selected VALUE=1>Managed let</option>
```

I received the error messages *Element is not currently visible*, but yet clearly exists within the framework. The web application I'm using has Select2 installed. I asked on selenium boards as to why select2 is having issues when I'm trying to create selenium scripts. If anyone knows how to bypass this please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: Look at the top voted answer, not the accepted one.

Comment: @JoshYu Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: I have tried similar, these things already. I believe the issue is that select2 is hiding the ID's

Comment: As @Guy indicated, the second option should work, there's really no reason it should not.  When you have a web element specifically tagged as "select" you should take advantage of the built-in class of select in Selenium to handle it properly.