# Python Selenium can't select dropdown (chrome webdriver)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Lp5.png) element, I want to select the **All** option, the corresponding HTML code is:

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="indicators_length"> 
  <label>
    <span class="result-mune">
      <span>Results </span>per page:
    </span> 
    <select name="indicators_length" aria-controls="indicators" class="jcf-hidden">
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="200">200</option>
      <option value="-1">All</option>
    </select>
    <span class="jcf-select jcf-unselectable">
      <span class="jcf-select-text">
        <span class="">25</span>
      </span>
      <span class="jcf-select-opener"></span>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

the `select` element is not highlighted using the browser **Inspect** method, looks like this drop down is triggered by js.
I tried to use the Select class described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value):

```
select = Select(self._wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located_by((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'indicators_length']//select[@name = 'indicators_length']")))
select.select_by_value('-1')
```

not working. and ActionChain method and even execute_script method, all not working. This bothers me a lot, hope somebody can help.

Comment: So, where is your error message? :)

Comment: can you post live example or URL?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov there is no error message, I've checked that the `select` element was correctly chosen. The thing is that  25 (the default) doesn't change to 'All', and the program raise no error.

Comment: @ewwink https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2019, it's this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't really need to select the `option` just click the `span` and it will set the option automatically.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("......")

# click "OK, I Agree" cookies
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.agree-button.eu-cookie-compliance-default-button').click()
# scroll down to make dropdown option visible
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h4.pane-title').location_once_scrolled_into_view

select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="result-mune"]/following-sibling::span')
select.click()
# wait until javascript generate fake option element because it actually span
time.sleep(1)
select.find_element_by_css_selector('ul li span[data-index="4"]').click()
```

Comment: thanks @ewwink, I will mark this as the right answer. It worked. I think the problem is selenium actions are performed based on the current webpage view point instead of the DOM, that's why `.location_once_scrolled_into_view` is needed, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("indicators_length")[0].value = 50;
```

If its created and loaded after page load make sure you add some sleep to let it render;

Comment: thanks bro, I tried this, nothing happened.
`self._browser.implicitly_wait(5)
self._browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("qs-rankings-indicators_length")[0].value = 500;')`

Comment: try using just python's normal time.sleep, if that wont help, it might not you can try running js via timeout (though its hardcoded) - so driver.execute_script('setTimeout(function() { document.getElementsByName("qs-rankings-indicators_length")[0].value = 500;}, 2000);')

Comment: another important thing... oonce the driver opens chrome/firefox (requiring testing with real browser and not headless), then ctrl+shift+c to open console, just paste your javascript and enter - i found this to be great way for testing/debugging :)

Comment: Nice tips, thanks bro. It turns out the problem is due to unexpected popups in this dynamics website, and if the target element is not visible in the current page view and there is no element to respond the action at the coordinate, then the action is omitted. But if there is other element, then throw `Other element would receive the action` exception

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the Selenium Select class, it can find the element but it cannot select an option from the element. Not sure whats going on, could be the class "jcf-hidden" on the element.

Having said that, I took a stab at it and below is my approach. Try it out, it worked on my system, you have to handle the clicking of "OK, I Agree" button click, I did that manually.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2019')

# Remove this nasty time.sleep and implement webdriver wait
# Handle the OK, I Agree
time.sleep(5)
i_agree = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class*="eu-cookie-compliance-default-button"]')
i_agree.click()


time.sleep(5)
# Open the Select
rankings_length = driver.find_element_by_id('qs-rankings_length')
select_opener = rankings_length.find_element_by_class_name('jcf-select-opener')
select_opener.click()

# loop through the list
select_content = rankings_length.find_element_by_class_name('jcf-list-content')
for content in select_content.find_elements_by_tag_name('li'):
    if content.text == 'All':
        content.click()
```

Comment: thanks @Satish, but I got this error, `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <span class="jcf-select-opener"></span> is not clickable at point (1107, 910). Other element would receive the click: <div id="sliding-popup" class="sliding-popup-bottom" style="height: auto; width: 100%; bottom: -2.82925px;">...</div>`

Comment: It is because you have to click the I Agree button, as I stated, I manually clicked it. Now the code is updated to click that button before finding the select opener

Comment: "Ok, I Agree" is not belong to `sliding-popup-bottom` class. I figured out how the problem comes anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer helped to solve your problem. Give it an upvote