# how to select a option on a web page drop down list using selenium with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I wanted to select the value "LK" in the drop down list on my web page. please help.

i tried to slect by xpath as follows

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(text(), 'GLOBAL')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'LK')]/..").click()
```

but i get following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

Below is the web element code im trying to fetch:

```
<select style="border-radius: 3px;" ng-model="selectedRcc.value" ng-options="item for item in ['LK', 'US', 'GLOBAL']" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="0" label="LK">LK</option>
    <option value="1" label="US">US</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected" label="GLOBAL">GLOBAL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

Comment: Ignore the selected answer and look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613320/2386774) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below xpath

```
//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']/option[.='LK']
```

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']/option[.='LK']").click()
```

Comment: I am getting following exception. Could you please help

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//Select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']/option[.='LK']"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)`

Comment: Can you check if the list box is part of the current window. `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']"))))`.

Comment: I am getting following output for print:- 0

Comment: So, it's not able to identify the list box first place. Can you please check if the list box present in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

When you have select element it always good to use selenium select class to select item from drop down menu.

```
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']"))
select.select_by_visible_text('GLOBAL')
select.select_by_visible_text('LK')
```

OR you can use index.

```
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']"))
select.select_by_index(0) #LK
select.select_by_index(2) #GLOBAL
```

To use above code you need to have following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Comment: I tried both codes but still get an error as follows:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']"}

FYI: I am using python 3

Comment: This shouldn't happen.verified on my pc and posted.Try put some sleep before accessing the element and then check.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i'll try that now

Comment: put some time.sleep(5) before call select element and check if it is working.if not then check any iframe available above your select element in DOM.

Comment: Still i get the same error.

code i used:

time.sleep(5)
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']"))
select.select_by_visible_text('GLOBAL')
select.select_by_visible_text('LK')

Comment: I could, but this is a VPN accessible site. I can share the web elements for you as much as you need. 
`<li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs ng-scope" ng-if="isAllowed('TOPIC_STAT')">
 <a href="" c="">
  <label>RCC :</label>
  <select style="border-radius: 3px;" ng-model="selectedRcc.value" ng-options="item for item in ['LK', 'US', 'GLOBAL']" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"><option value="0" label="LK">LK</option><option value="1" label="US">US</option><option value="2" selected="selected" label="GLOBAL">GLOBAL</option></select>
 </a>
</li>`

Comment: I have tried testing on a differrent machine, but i still get the same exception. Could you plz help @KunduK

Comment: are you on windows or mac or linux?

Comment: window 10 -KunduK