# Find and click an element inside a script element

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to change store location on a website with python and selenium.
Selenium IDE addon from Firefox gives me a sequence. The sequence works within selenium IDE from Firefox but I cannot get it to work from within Python (Spyder). The element I want to click is inside a script and no tool can find an element inside a script. Beautifulsoup can not do it, neither can selenium.
With the following code I try to get a product price in every store so I need to change the store (it is that yellow button in the top left corner and then the dropdown list) to every store from the dropdown list and **scrape** the page source for product price. But whenever I try "driver.find_element_by_" I get "Unable to locate element: "

The click sequence is recorded with Selenium IDE addon from Firefox.
Or maybe there is a faster way than selenium to switch between shops and get the product price. I could not do it just with Beautifulsoup.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='d:\Work\geckodriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.castorama.pl/deska-14x90x540-eslov-jodel-1-94-id-1105153.html'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_id("market-name").click() #Unable to locate element
driver.find_element_by_id("shop-selection-master-infostore").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='geolocation_popup_select_market_chosen']/a/span").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='geolocation_popup_select_market_chosen']/div/ul/li[2]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the cookie bar:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='d:\Work\geckodriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.castorama.pl/deska-14x90x540-eslov-jodel-1-94-id-1105153.html'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick="bold.cookie.closeCookie();"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('shop-selection-master').click()
```

---

Purists won't like it but you can also use javascript

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#shop-selection-master').click();")
```

---

selecting options is covered extensively here: [Selenium - Python - drop-down menu option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-option-value)

You have the id of the parent `select`: `geolocation-popup-select-market`.

Comment: After dismissing the cookie bar the line driver.find_element_by_id('shop-selection-master').click() still fails to find the element. However, "driver.execute_script" does the trick and brings up the popup window. I switch to it with "driver.switch_to.active_element;     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='geolocation_popup_select_market_chosen']/a/span").click();driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='geolocation_popup_select_market_chosen']/div/ul/li[5]").click()
". Then, the page configures itself to the selected shop and then I am unable to switch to the default content.

Comment: You probably need to loop through setting the store each time

Comment: Can the selection of the store (executing the script) and then scrapping the webpage content be done with PyQt? Selenium is painfully slow.