# How to select an option from a dropdown of non select tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to select a value from a dropdown menu. I tried a lot of solutions found here but nothing work, sometimes I have the error can't scroll to view.

Code trials:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
browser.get('https://dzairannonces.com/posts/create');
mySelectElement = browser.find_element_by_id('parentId')
dropDownMenu = Select(mySelectElement)
```

I want to select a value from the dropdown form and another value from the second dropdown form that appear when we select the first one

I tried this code too and doesn't work

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time


class Drpdowm(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def test_drpdown(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get('https://dzairannonces.com/posts/create')
        time.sleep(10) # Let the user actually see something!
        s1=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('parentId'))

        print(s1.options)


        for opt in s1.options:
            s1.select_by_value(' 315 ')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: How are you trying to select the second option.

Comment: If selecting an option in one drop down causes the second drop down to regenerate its options, then you need to wait for the option to appear in the second drop down before selecting it.

Comment: i cant even make selection form first dropdown menu

Comment: See specifically [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613320/2386774).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To select an option e.g. **Automobiles** from a dropdown menu of **non** `<select>` tag you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://dzairannonces.com/posts/create')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.select2-selection__rendered#select2-parentId-container"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='select2-results']/ul//li[@class='select2-results__option' and contains(., 'Automobiles')]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: nonSelect]

Comment: its works very well , sorry for my bad english, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be

```
s1=Select(driver.find_element_by_id('parentId'))
s1.select_by_value('315')
```

[HTML attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) are very strict when it comes to extra spaces or line breaks, you need to provide value **exactly as it is**

See [Select Support](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) chapter for Python WebDriver APIs designed for working with [`<select>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

With regards to overall test design a good idea is implementing [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model), it will allow you to split UI and test logic and make your test robust, reliable and easier to refactor. See [Page Objects](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-objects) chapter for more information.