# Selenium Python : pick element from drop down in a span

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

i am relatively new to Selenium , I am working on a web browser automation project and one of the action is to pick a element from an drop down menu please find below the html code.

```
<span id="export_menu" class="ui-button drop-down export-menu" tabindex="0" role="application">
<span class="menu_text">Export</span>
<span class="drop-down-menu ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<ul class="export-actions"><li><header>Export Report</header>
    <ul><li class="menu-action"><input type="button" value="CSV" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="export_csv" data-format="csv" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></li></ul>
    <ul><li class="menu-action"><input type="button" value="PDF" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="export_pdf" data-format="pdf" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></li></ul>
    <ul><li class="menu-action"><input type="button" value="Schedule Export" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="schedule" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></li></ul></li></ul>
</ul>
</span>
```

I tried following on Python, which give out error as below

```
driver.find_element_by_id("export_menu").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("export_csv").click()
```

*selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view*

after some research I also tried following, which simply *timeouts*

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="export_csv"]'))).click()
```

requesting help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick the element with *value* as **CSV** from an drop-down-menu you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ui-button.drop-down.export-menu#export_menu"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.export-actions li.menu-action > input.button.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all#export_csv"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-button drop-down export-menu' and @id='export_menu']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='export-actions']//li[@class='menu-action']/input[@class='button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' and @id='export_csv']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to select an option from a dropdown of non select tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399713/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-of-non-select-tag/57402060#57402060)

Answer (score 0):

Try first clicking the `<ul>`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="export-actions"]'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="export_csv"]'))).click()
```

Comment: @ Moshe, thank, for some reason this does not seem to work for me, it timeouts after a while