# How can I click on an option from a dropdown menu in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to choose a option in the following menu:

```
<select class="form-control" id="DayBirthDate" name="DayBirthDate"> . 
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>


day1 = 5
day = driver.find_element_by_id('DayBirthDate')
for option in day.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == day1:
        option.click()
```

but can't seem to find a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML having select for dropdown so use Selenium Select class itself instead of using standard script

Example:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('DayBirthDate'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('1')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('1')

# select by index
select.select_by_index(1)
```

Use any one , it will work for you

Source:

[How to select a drop-down menu option value with Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-option-value-with-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is Not Working beacuse You have declare the value `day1 =5` which is integer value and when return the value `option.text` it is string value so code can't compare those values.

Change to `day1 ='5'`

```
day1 ='5'
day = driver.find_element_by_id('DayBirthDate')
for option in day.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):        
    if option.text == day1:
        option.click()
```