# How to select a drop-down menu value wihtout an id with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I need to select an element/item from a drop-down menu that doesn't have an id element using Python and Selenium.

The piece of HTML code:

```
<mbo-transaction-mode-select mode="filters.mode" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <select class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model="mode" ng-options="value for (key,value) in vm.modes">
        <option value="" class="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option label="LIVE" value="string:LIVE">LIVE</option>
        <option label="TEST" value="string:TEST">TEST</option>
    </select>
```

The current option I found on Stackoverflow or Google used the *Select* method, but that option used *find_element_by_id* which I unfortunately don't have.
I tried to use:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-model='mode']"))
select.select_by_visible_text('LIVE')
```

But this gave the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@ng-model='mode']

Is there another way for me the select the dropdown and one of its options?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python

Comment: Can you locate `input[ng-model='mode']` in Dev Tools?

Comment: @Pinaki, that is what I was referring to with the issue that its using finding an element by ID, which isn't an option for me :(

Comment: @Sers, I'm unaware how to use Dev Tools.

Comment: [How to search element in Devtools](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/inspect-elements-with-chrome-developer-tools/). Can you share the URL?

Comment: @Sers Unfortunately it's behind a login.
I did run the Dev tools search using input[ng-model='mode'], but _No matches_ found.... Altough the HTML code provides: ng-model="mode"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix your xpath, as here:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model='mode']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text('LIVE')
```

Comment: You can find more information about xpath here: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: @Evhgeniy Chiruk Now I have the problem with using select, that I won't be able to run this headless/unatended.... Is this avoidable?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @Evhgeniy Chiruk, When running headless it gives: _selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated_ (or trough a Scheduled Task it automatically runs the script, non headless, in the background and I guess same error occurs)

Comment: Add this: `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);` before selecting by text

Comment: I still get a _SyntaxError: invalid syntax_ for the _(JavascriptExecutor) browser)_ part (specifically the browser)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just recently answered such a question with java and inserted the code from Java) I updated the answer)

Comment: No problem, really appreciatie the help..!! Now i get: _TypeError: Object of type Select is not JSON serializable_ for that line

Comment: driver.execute_script = browser.execute in my case right? Then i get the _selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated_ again :(

Comment: Right. But does the same code work without --headless?

Comment: Yeah, your original version already worked on headless. The problem I need is to get it working headless, cause it needs to run during midnight (pref. through a task scheduler).... I guess I phrased my first comment wrong? :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206576/discussion-between-evgeniy-chiruk-and-jebo).