# How to click on a drop-down menu item using selenium with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, automation

I tried to use xpath search but it didn't work for me. The idea is that I pass the mouse over "Nota Fiscal" and then go down with the mouse in the drop-down menu and click on "Emissão". The drop-down menu is inside a frame called "pag_principal" and the rest of the code (which is not here) works within that frame, that is, selenium has switched windows and frames correctly...
[Inspect elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYgkb.jpg)
My problem is: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view.

How can i fix this?

The code I made to try is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

bot.get('https://www.nfs-e.net/fiscalweb.php')
time.sleep(3)

campo_login = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='login_temp']") 
campo_login.clear()
campo_login.send_keys(self.usuario)
password = bot.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passw_temp"]')
password.clear()
password.send_keys(self.senha)   
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(6)
# handling to new window
bot.switch_to.window(bot.window_handles[1])
bot.maximize_window()

def envio(self):
   bot = self.bot
   time.sleep(5)
   bot.switch_to.frame("pag_principal")
   time.sleep(2)

# this is the part that I want selenium to select the item "Emissão" in the drop-down menu "Nota Fiscal"

   Nota_fiscal = WebDriverWait(bot, 100000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span"))).click()
   time.sleep(2)
   Emissão = bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span').click()
```

[Trying by using select]

```
Menu = bot.find_element_by_class_name("menu") 
mySelectElement = bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/a/span') 
dropDownMenu = Select(mySelectElement) 
WebDriverWait(bot, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span")))
dropDownMenu.select_by_visible_text('Emissão') 
time.sleep(2) 
Emissão = bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/ul[1]/li[5]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span').click()
```

[I want to click on "Emissão" within the "Nota Fiscal" drop-down menu (I don't know how to edit html)]

```html
    <div class="titulo_sistema">Nota Fiscal Eletrônica</div>  <ul class="menu"><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span> Globais </span></a><div><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_sub_menu">Cadastros</span></a><div><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_sub_menu">Diversos</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(1026,118,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Alterar Senha/E-Mail">Alterar Senha/E-Mail</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3565,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="CPFCNPJ x Email">CPFCNPJ x Email</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3561,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Procuração Digital">Procuração Digital</span></a></li></ul></div></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_sub_menu">Pessoas/Endereços</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3503,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Bairro">Bairro</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3504,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Logradouro">Logradouro</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(1014,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Pessoa">Pessoa</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3572,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Estrangeiros">Estrangeiros</span></a></li></ul></div></li></ul></div></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_sub_menu">Consultas</span></a><div><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_sub_menu">Economico</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3517,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Atividades">Atividades</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3526,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Cadastro Econômico">Cadastro Econômico</span></a></li></ul></div></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_sub_menu">Pessoas/Endereços</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3525,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Cidade">Cidade</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3506,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Pessoa">Pessoa</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(3573,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Estrangeiros">Estrangeiros</span></a></li></ul></div></li></ul></div></li></ul></div></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Autorização</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(9710,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Solicitação de Cancelamento de NFSe">Solicitação de Cancelamento de NFSe</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(4505,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Utilização de NFSe">Utilização de NFSe</span></a></li></ul></div></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Configurações</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(4514,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Cabeçalho da NFSe">Cabeçalho da NFSe</span></a></li></ul></div></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Consulta</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(4524,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="NFS-e Prestadas">NFS-e Prestadas</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(4506,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="NFS-e Tomadas">NFS-e Tomadas</span></a></li></ul></div></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Nota Fiscal</span></a><div><ul><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(9598,656,event)" href="javascript:void(0)">**<span class="span_menu" title="Emissão">Emissão</span>**</a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(9597,109,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Cancelamento">Cancelamento</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(4501,101,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Gerenciamento de Notas">Gerenciamento de Notas</span></a></li><li><a onclick="carrega_rotina_menu(4511,436,event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="span_menu" title="Exportação">Exportação</span></a></li></ul></div></li>     <li>        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="parent.window.close(0,event)"><span> Sair </span></a>     </li>  </ul>  <ul style="float:right;">     <li style="width:25px;max-height:25px;padding:3px;text-align:center;cursor: pointer;color:#104E8B;" title="Início" id="home-button">         <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:18px;padding-top:3px;cursor: pointer;" onclick="abre_tela_inicial();"></i>     </li>     <li style="width:25px;max-height:25px;text-align:center;padding:3px;" title="Usuário" id="perfil-usuario">         <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:18px;padding-top:3px;cursor: pointer;" onclick="abrePerfilUsuario()"></i>     </li>     <li style="float:right;height:35px;margin-right: 35px; padding-left:5px;background:none;position:block;" id="lipesquisa" name="lipesquisa">         <input type="text" id="container_pesquisa" name="container_pesquisa" class="container_busca campo_externo_suggest" placeholder="Pesquisa" onfocus="focusPesquisa(this, 'in')" onblur="focusPesquisa(this, 'out')" suggest="true" autocomplete="off"><script>  $(document).ready(function(){$("#container_pesquisa").autocompletepesquisa({"aCamposVisualizacao":["frm_tit"],"iRotina":"16","sCampoProcurado":"frm_tit","sCampos":"container_pesquisa:frm_tit","sSessao":"3cbtrg9e3c1eil54cupilua6s1","sUrlAbrir":"","sNome":"form","iRotChamou":"0","iAcaChamou":"20","bAutoComplete":true,"aAjaxCampos":["container_pesquisa"],"bAjaxComplete":true});}); if ($.browser.msie) {      if($.browser.version == 9.0 || $.browser.version == 8.0) {          $('#container_pesquisa').css('padding-top','3px');          $('#container_pesquisa').css('background-position','5px -1px');      }  }</script>     </li>  </ul>
```

First I need to hover over these elements for the drop-down menu to appear

```html
<span>Nota Fiscal</span>
```

And the element I want to click on is this

```html
<span class="span_menu" title="Emissão">Emissão</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)

Comment: Hello, @KentKostelac, I tried to use select like that but I can't use it with span elements  
Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <span>

Comment: I've edited your question. In the future just edit your question. And then add a comment to bring attention to it. As you can see; Code written in a comment is not readable

Comment: More importantly. You should try using attributes to find the elements you need to use. Copy pasting the xpath from a browser is not going to work in all cases. Also in your xpath. You are selecting a <span> not a <select>

Comment: Give us a minimal verifiable sample of the HTML you are trying to select from so we can identify what is wrong with your xpath. Because right now all I can tell you is that your xpath is wrong. And a picture does not count.

Comment: @KentKostelac I think I added a sample of the HTML, I'm not sure if this is what you requested

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is completely wrong. Of course nothing is going to happen when you press a span. Try clicking its parent that is an <a>

And try using proper xpaths and not just something you copy pasted from the browser.

```
//span[@class='span_menu' and @title='Emissão']::parent/a
```

I repeat. If you provide a minimal HTML example. It will be much easier to help you.