# How to click an item from non select drop-down menu with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, drop-down-menu, webdriverwait

Trying to select other financial statements (default is income statement), as well as toggle between the second list of Annual/Quarterly. I can narrow down to get the attributes of the lists but I'm not able to interact with the list.

```
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

symbol = 'bmo'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://web.tmxmoney.com/financials.php?qm_symbol={}'.format(symbol))
time.sleep(2)
dropdown = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.qmod-dropdown_toggle.qmod-type-toggle + ul.qmod-dropdown-menu > li > a')

for option in dropdown:
    if option.get_attribute('innerText') == 'Balance Sheet':
        option.send_keys('Balance Sheet')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)

Comment: I wasn't able to use the same method. .click() didn't work and there's no 'select' class. I did noticed that inside the <a> tag, the class value for the currently displayed option would have a value of " qmod-active", and when I select another option, the class of the de-selected option will be "" and the newly selected one will take on the value of " qmod-active", but I don't know how to change it (very new at this).

Comment: I was able to change the class of 'Balance Sheet' using the following but the selection is still stuck in the original default of income statement. driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class',' qmod-active')", option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the [dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown) option with text as **Balance Sheet** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver.get('https://web.tmxmoney.com/financials.php?qm_symbol=bmo')
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[text()='Financials for Bank of Montreal']")))
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,600)")
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='qmod-dropdown_toggle qmod-type-toggle']/span[text()='Income Statement']")))).perform()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='qmod-dropdown-menu']//li/a[text()='Balance Sheet']"))).click()
  ```