# Nested for loops with a function

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a code for chrome driver to extract data

I have a code like this:

```
def click_all_options(path):
    try: 
        for option in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(path):
            option.click()
        return True
    except StaleElementReferenceException: 
        return False

select1 = '/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'
select2 = '/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'

result = click_all_options(select1)
if not result:
        click_all_options(select2)
```

The problem is that this doesn't lead to a nested for loop. How can I tweak this to get a nested for loop?

Comment: You don't have nested for loop in the code you posted. And this is not how you should handle `<select>` dropdown with Selenium, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613320/5168011)

Comment: @Guy this is not a select function. I could have named it A or B

Comment: No, this is a `<select>` tag with `<option>` tags in it. You shouldn't click it directly, you have an API just for dealing with that kind of dropdowns.

Comment: @Guy I don't understand. It would be helpful if you post it as an answer. It will help others and I can upvote too

Comment: I don't really know what the original question is so I can't post an answer, and even if I posted it as an answer it will be exactly the same as in the answer I linked in my first comment (look at alecxe's top voted one, not the accepted one). Look at it or google "selenium python select option from select dropdown".

Comment: @guy but there is no select option here.

Comment: Yes there is, this is what you target in your xpath.

Comment: yes, but thats just a variable name

Comment: I'm talking about the xpath. In `select1` and `select2`. It targets `<option>` tags inside `<select>` tag.

Comment: @Guy what is your suggestion?