# Scraping Prices in AUD from USD in Python Selenium - Web Scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm new in Python Selenium webdriver. I'm writing a script to scrape the prices in this site https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Digital-Cameras/ci/9811/N/4288586282. But I want to scrape the prices in AUD from USD. You will see a dropdown list (Currency) in the footer of this site. This dropdown list will show you a list of currencies. After clicking this dropdown, select currency as Australian Dollar. Immediately the site refreshes and shows prices in both USD and AUD. I need to scrape the prices only in AUD not in USD.  How should I do that?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Digital-Cameras/ci/9811/N/4288586282")

price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-selenium = "uppedDecimalPriceFirst"]')

for i in range(0, len(price)):

    print("Prices in USD : " + price[i].text)

driver.close()
```

Output:

`Price : $3,899`

Expected Output:

`Price : $5462.50`

[Currency List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egtq7.png)

[Prices in AUD after selecting the dropdown as AUD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHn3H.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's bit different approach, not using `selenium`.

The currency code is passed as one of the cookie values. So, you can grab all cookies, parse them, and send the request.

The down side of this is that this gets expired pretty quickly.

```
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "referer": "https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Digital-Cameras/ci/9811/N/4288586282",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
}


url = "https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Digital-Cameras/ci/9811/N/4288586282"

rawdata = """
__cfduid=d3bdb54963e368d44b5e6884f7d73e51c1602143416; dcid=1602143417279-81384671; mapp=0; cartId=22850067748; locale=en; aperture-be-commit-id=n/a; D_SID=62.96.159.233:3ohrnHfDBx/FJKw5rqCYwC+IsePPxHUI0sfORzmYLhg; aperture-be-commit-id=n/a; ftr_ncd=6; __cfruid=be69be948af2b86ea99a0bb76bfe96f1f2e949cf-1602145612; BHFOTO_ENSIGHTEN_PRIVACY_BANNER_VIEWED=1; _fbp=fb.1.1602146128792.1914192519; SSID_C=CABIZh0AAAAAAAC5xH5fXRRAGLnEfl8DAAAAAAAAAAAA4th-XwANyA; SSSC_C=333.G6881153579923543133.3|0.0; my_cookie=!qltlzDwS7kQ/zfYbOLfqaMDV2Dx0K84+1Np3voLzYtZJpbdmGM1aRtff/nmQJ3K2+8RhwqtQU7mqko0njfvupkBbTQcSqyQsQqzSit5MsDRmQAltfZQJhGdGL7+7DP37WbBdLTWyfrIPcBHn72OdD66SAh/iiPaOqzyT2wI6ifXP0la2fofeIPxkkD5gcQkibDJFDdy6FQ==; build=20200925v10-20200925v10; TS0188dba5_77=080f850069ab28005f16d063631902e3794db1c0edc9f4c6f6ef0d1eac6527cf99ad1b8c27823c9b69571149d6b96f090814e6aa558240000b1940db61379359c992a1feb444e1125e0df1fe6100edbe2d3b20d0751edcc1b64b1e00a346fdc9f9abcfadd468699787be03341403bd5353fdb3a2e5d8deb9; cookieID=221356360871602130569547; sessionKey=1e8aaddd-62ef-4dee-82c8-6f35fcc57a71; utkn=2870955d449ed2798d6d41e4b34cb3d7; SSRT_C=JeR-XwQBAA; SSPV_C=NOgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAA; pvid=1602151461750-67341336; TS01c1e793=01ec39615f9aa795b03ad73db5ae3ea9bfaccd846205e248eefb69ecbb9655964dbd97008d269c15dc4da0f79c2a904db5fbb4141ad60dd5e19c1cc1945cac3435d54cc822813399ba0563719ef2813d1e35f54430; TS01472329=01ec39615fa04d4ed3ebebb173c30f0c52eb5a398a02c6c93717c12f32ed8f6055a8528125ec9a7ae65ddb2b93d1ec5f99cb9ccd51141361e57c4a0c54bd1b9ee137e996cb; __cf_bm=78744b2be0c5790321c0fca10c6e9f49811df789-1602151463-1800-AePVD5wqk3ezKZPdl1gG2H/9EkXrrYhfPhrO21Gd/A1AXsfyYZ1fAzpSulkj6Xjvm6uigtGKCUxaJwuohJ0a96nrAfe18dExkTncLlDc/8JQFjcTyDM12xKX5H2bdGrE2Q==; D_IID=80EBCC02-1B08-3947-9BBA-B7DE344C0CC2; D_UID=57631A10-AD80-379F-B193-E3144BE816A6; D_ZID=3E416AAF-00A8-38F3-8951-18E587B713F3; D_ZUID=DD74D4B2-8918-3C31-86CE-559CD726FA66; D_HID=10B0A111-9447-3A05-9D56-B60C9EAF8E57; uui=800.952.1815|; TS0119d048=01ec39615fa9a4fe4090a627d643ced60a42832e7505e248eefb69ecbb9655964dbd97008dfb49159bf4a23094ef84f4adea4642e74d190625c36f2dea052a14c1a672d5414f4d44f6abe7dece2da3d4b346965a974f110d88d050837c31a114c3cab7eb945e08f785ed3175f6370325edc449813d420357a41783aacbf1ed6284c67427c4b9e6beea94f05f3e544e7d2e8477c0e326fa6bca1d24896f750eb456e07d71135edc2e20bbb3214751b624bf57cf6a7bfc2de1a5012e41a12bb765b0518572b5; JSESSIONID=P28Hq0Itv8QxVhGCV0uNtM3VtH_upfSq!230185629; TS0188dba5=01ec39615f507d745bcb1186593a0c4b69a62e6cafecbc31323cbb6cc681bcdb22e0b477baa125ba7d0a82f94f7c3d8be8a5accb5725a00585f2206c375d2f0fcc1b23e501f4ae68f76fbdd16dc18929fd78ad8c360ea424f8b14a1a3a19c4ebcbf0d33a56; forterToken=4d9bbef1ef224c25a2d18be549978618_1602151464974__UDF43_6; TopBarCart=0|0; TS01e1f1fd=01ec39615f2d39ed2dad52a73051682081c331a6fc855ff8177aa2b38dd47ee53287ef19ce9149fa03daf9e245f740107ae7418eac935eda28bf46197e4c0912c7dec3d9e9809839dfcb4f3ba2b8578ef3aae5f6757093319d1016d4672421656801801d7ea0c51b9fee103e26b11616c645918809698bacf0f9d2ff7c417c991064c74acf03fb9615419622d2f45342df9551e738; TS01d628c4=01ec39615f10de3e4775311fe5669af070e90c5813855ff8177aa2b38dd47ee53287ef19ce49233bd9f6eaae68737da6b926ec55365d9ba728190cac27d9b2935672943d9703024c3347affe42969f5767337f2aaeb26763a2924b02d56124b0fde952683157cf258c2ee5ac1e8b34d61653354138d80dfcfdec9c05278f413d99b988b82b598ac9cbf9d13cb074d64f3964183a340e1eec613eedff8014938db974924ef90a531f09bebeffe76b18ef64d0544f71236390b7f94621442a9a77bb33f8710dcdfb8456c5ddc25c72ec9c9bb5d9bfcd; app_cookie=1602151489; lpi=cat=2,cur=AUD,app=D,lang=E,view=L,lgdin=N,cache=release-WEB-20200924v10-BHJ-DVB25488-3,ipp=24,view=L,sort=BS,priv=Y,state=NY; dpi=cat=2,cur=AUD,app=D,lang=E,view=L,lgdin=N,cache=release-WEB-20200924v10-BHJ-DVB25488-3"""
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie.load(rawdata)

cookies = {}
for key, morsel in cookie.items():
    cookies[key] = morsel.value

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")


p_name = soup.find_all("span", {"data-selenium": "miniProductPageProductName"})
p_conv = soup.find_all("div", {"data-selenium": "miniProductPageProductConversion"})
f_currency = soup.find_all("div", {"data-selenium": "miniProductPagePricingForeignCurrency"})

product_name = [t.getText() for t in p_name]
price = [t.find("span").getText() for t in p_conv]
foreign_price = [t.getText() for t in f_currency]

for n, u, a, in zip(product_name, price, foreign_price):
    print(f"{n} - {u} - {a}")
```

Sample output:

```
Canon EOS R5 Mirrorless Digital Camera (Body Only) - $3,89900 - AUD $5,462.50
Sony Alpha a7S III Mirrorless Digital Camera (Body Only) - $3,49800 - AUD $4,900.70
Canon EOS 5D Mark IV DSLR Camera Body with Accessory Kit - $2,49900 - AUD $3,501.10
Canon EOS R6 Mirrorless Digital Camera (Body Only) - $2,49900 - AUD $3,501.10
Sony Alpha a7 III Mirrorless Digital Camera Body with Accessory Kit - $1,99800 - AUD $2,799.20
Sony ZV-1 Digital Camera - $79800 - AUD $1,118.00
Canon EOS R6 Mirrorless Digital Camera with 24-105mm f/4-7.1 Lens - $2,79900 - AUD $3,921.40
```

To get the raw cookie string, copy the `cookie` value from the request Header after setting up the currency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `.send_keys()` function.
For example in this line of code here. I believe you should get the `<select>` tag.

Probably a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python).

```
#put the id value there of the dropdown tag, or find it by class if it has a class only, You can do it by xpath.. anyways just get the element :)
dropdown_currency = browser.find_element_by_id("ID-value")


dropdown_currency .send_keys("Australian Dollar")
```

Do this before you start your scraping process...

### UPDATE!

I did not know that it doesn't use a `<select>` tag so try this. Since the value of the dropdown depends on the `p` tag (go check it out), a way to do this is to set the `innerHTML` of that `p` tag to what you want, in this case
**"Australian Dollar"**. `Take note you still won't be scraping the Australian Dollars price cause it's on a different tag.`

**But you can still do it by yourself since the prices of AUD are shown now, you can do that EXACTLY what you did to get the USD. You just need to look out for its `elements` or `tags` again**

I also suggest you try implementing those what I commented out, it's a good practice especially with selenium, it waits for elements to load up also is a good way to avoid errors with getting elements. `Btw 20 there is for to wait 20 seconds`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Digital-Cameras/ci/9811/N/4288586282")

#try:
#   items_container = WebDriverWait(my_browser,20).until(
#       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"featured"))
#       )

div_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_class_name("currencySelect")
p_value = div_dropdown.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Australian Dollar';",p_value)



price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-selenium = "uppedDecimalPriceFirst"]')

for i in range(0, len(price)):

    print("Prices in USD : " + price[i].text)

#driver.close()
```

---

**With WebDriverWait**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Digital-Cameras/ci/9811/N/4288586282")

try:
    '''
    This is the class value of the block of code where it contains the 
    listings to be scraped
    '''
    products_block_class = "listings_17u0Luvydb9lNARSsSl8xJ"
    
    items_container = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,products_block_class))
        )


    div_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_class_name("currencySelect")
    p_value = div_dropdown.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Australian Dollar';",p_value)



    price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-selenium = "uppedDecimalPriceFirst"]')

    for i in range(0, len(price)):

        print("Prices in USD : " + price[i].text)

    #driver.close()
except BaseException as error:
    print("What happened? ",error)
```

---**OUTPUT SAMPLE**----

[image: aud]

Comment: Thank you so much. The program runs fine. But it does not display any output to the console

Comment: What output? the USD? Cause I'm sure the USD is still there.. what do you mean exactly. I tried it out and it worked tho

Comment: Made some updates for the with `WebDriverWait`. For the AUD scraping , you need to scrape it again just like how you did with USD, however the elements are just different but the process on how you would do it is just the same. You can do it :)

Comment: Yeah. this program runs fine. But I'm not getting the prices in AUD, it shows the prices only in USD. Whenever I click any dropdown in the Currency (dropdown list), the site doesn't shows the prices in selected currency. For example, when I click the "Australian Dollar" dropdown in the currency list, the site shows the prices only in USD.