# Select an option with Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

I am trying to select South Africa from the option list below:

```
<select name="from_country" id="from_country" data-role="none" class="button-negative button-negative-country-select classic" >
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="ZW" selected="selected">Zimbabwe</option>
    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
</select>
```

I have tried using xpath like the solotion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python) :

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='from_country']/option[text()='South Africa']").click()`

but this results in:

> Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException

I have then assumed that maybe the form is been rendered after the page has finished loading and I applied WebDriverWait:

`WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_located_to_be_selected((By.XPATH,"//select[@name='from_country']/option[text()='South Africa']"))).click()`

and it results in:

> Exception has occurred: TimeoutException

If I use Chrome developer tools and search for the element using xpath it shows that the xpath is valid.

The webpage in question: https://www.mukuru.com/sa/send-money-to-nigeria/

Comment: Avoid using `click()` for `<select>` tags. Check the all the answers within the post you have mentioned within this question.

Comment: Can you share the actual link?

Comment: Hi @AbrarAhmed I have edited the qustion and added the link

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB. Thank you. But even if I remove the clik() method it still cant locate the element.

Comment: @tendaitakas Isn't South Africa the already selected option? That's what I see.

Comment: @AbrarAhmed afaik, OP wants a generic solution, selecting _South Africa_ was just an example.

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes. It is different `iframe` that is why the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element target inside a frame:

```
<iframe src="https://mobile.mukuru.com/mobi/pricecheck?country_shortcode=ZA&amp;iframe=1" class="homeIframe" name="calculatorFrame" scrolling="no" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" allowfullscreen="" width="340px" height="430px" frameborder="1">
    #document
        ....
        ....
        YOUR TARGET HERE
```

You need switch it first, recommendations using `.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`.

To select dropdown you can use `Select` class, with `.select_by_visible_text('...')` method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver.get('https://www.mukuru.com/sa/send-money-to-nigeria/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe.homeIframe')))
drop_down = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'from_country'))))
drop_down.select_by_visible_text('South Africa')
```

Comment: Thanks. i hadnt noticed it was in an iframe. it worked