# Element <option> could not be scrolled into view Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm new to selenium and facing issue while selecting an option from the dropdown.

HTML Code:

```
<select id="fileselection" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" name="fileselection" onchange="function1('SELECTEDFILES', 'True')" multiple="" data-width="100%" data-style="btn-info" data-action-box="true" data-live-search="true" data-size="5" tabindex="-98">
    <option value="URL_OF_FILE_1">
       Filename_1.zip
    </option>
    <option value="URL_OF_FILE_2">
       Filename_2.zip
    </option>
</select>
```

URL also contains the filename

**Example:**

[www.yahoo.com/Filename_1.zip](http://www.yahoo.com/Filename_1.zip)

[www.yahoo.com/Filename_2.zip](http://www.yahoo.com/Filename_2.zip)

**My code:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='fileselection']//option[contains(.,'Filename_1.zip')]")))
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='fileselection']//option[contains(.,'Filename_1.zip')]")
ele.click()
```

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='fileselection']//option[@value='URL_OF_FILE_1')]")))
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='fileselection']//option[@value='URL_OF_FILE_1')]")
ele.click()
```

I'm getting the error at the last step(ele.click()). Wait and find element steps are working fine.

`Element <option> could not be scrolled into view`

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)

Comment: @DeadSec - I have tried every single solution provided in the link you've shared. Code works fine till the time it encounters a click() or select().
Tried using select_by_index(), visible_text(), by_value(). No luck, not sure what exactly is happening.

Comment: Try opening the dropdown first clicking in the select.

Comment: @DeadSec Could you please share any answer or reference link. Thanks for your help!

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='fileselection']").click()

Comment: If you want i can help you in a faster way then via StackOverflow in discord if you want: https://discord.gg/vHQxm7AK

Comment: Getting the below error while using the above solution


`Message: Element <select id='fileselection' class='selectpicker show-menu-arrow' name='fileselectoin'> could not be scrolled into view`

Comment: Use webdriver wait to wait until the element is visible

Comment: Below code solved my problem ```ActionChains(driver).click(element).send_keys(Filename_1.zip).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()```