# how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to select and click one of the options as shown in this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWxAQ.jpg

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/bunai/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/login.php")

# identify username, password and signin elements
driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys("3480199")

driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys("12")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()

time.sleep(1.0)
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/configure_roster.php")
time.sleep(0.1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form/ul[@id='configure']/li[1]/p[2]/input[@id='tMoves_102787072_1']").click()
time.sleep(0.1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='cBox']/p[@class='center'][1]/select[@id='MoveA']").click()
```

I only mange to click the option but i was not able to go down and select other option. Any idea which code should be used there?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a select element so this should answer your question.
[how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# Identify dropdown with Select
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("path to select element"))

# Select by:
element.select_by_visible_text("Text from dropdown")

# Or
element.select_by_index(0)

# Or
element.select_by_value("value from dropdown")
```

Comment: Thanks change the title.   Any idea how to select the options. I only want to pick the first one there