# Unable to Click on Dropdown using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to select an element from a dropdown but getting an error.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="childContextDDL" data-filter="contains" data-role="dropdownlist" data-template="dcf-context-picker" data-value-field="Value" data-text-field="DisplayText" data-bind="events: { change: childContextListChange }, source: childContextList.ChildContextList" style="display: none;">
<option value="1">NATION</option>
<option value="12">ATLANTIC</option>
<option value="16">CHARLOTTE, NC</option>
```

And this is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("childContextDDL"))
print('MySelect is: ',mySelect)
mySelect.select_by_visible_text('ATLANTIC')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

What's the possible reason for getting this error? I'm very new to Selenium.

I also want to click on that element after selecting it.

Comment: After selecting, I also want to click on that element.

Comment: You can find an answer to this question here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)

Comment: You can find an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python

Comment: If you look at the 2nd answer in your link, I've done exactly that but it still isn't working

Comment: I've added the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the style within the html was set to none. So I had to first change that style to block to make it visible and then proceed with the clicking operation.

Here's the code that worked:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('childContextDDL').style.display = 'block';")

mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("childContextDDL"))
print('MySelect is: ',mySelect)
mySelect.select_by_visible_text('ATLANTIC')

randomClick = driver.find_element_by_id('dcf-user-info')
randomClick.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it says it is not currently visible, you should try pausing the code with one of this options:

```
time.sleep(1) #This states to your code to stop for 1 second and the continue with the work.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_visible(BY.value, "12")) # tells the driver to wait a maximum of ten seconds until the value "12" is visible for the driver.
```

Comment: Can you please fill in the blanks for my code, it'll be really helpful. I'm finding the syntax of that confusing for now

Comment: Edited! Tell me if it works just with this :)

Comment: The problem is that the element is present but not visible when the interaction is attempted. So I don't see how waiting for the presence will help. Perhaps you should use `EC.element_to_be_visible()`?

Comment: Yes, it is more logical your argument.

Comment: Should this be before 'mySelect'? Because I tried that and now getting this error: AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Just in case the problem can be resolved with this, first use time.sleep(10) after defining mySelect. It is more or less like the WebDriverWait but in a less fancy way. If it doesn't work with time.sleep() then the problem is another thing

Comment: I talked to my colleague and he said that it's because the the display style is none. So I have to somehow make that visible? Do you know how to do that? At the end in html, you'll see 'style: display none'

Comment: I've added the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `mySelect` element (the dropdown menu) is not visible.
So please try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)

mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("childContextDDL"))

actions.move_to_element(mySelect).perform()
mySelect.select_by_visible_text('ATLANTIC')
```

If the above doesn't work (I can't see the actual site you are working on), the following can work instead in the element has to be tapped to become enabled

```
action = TouchActions(driver)
action.tap(mySelect).perform()
mySelect.select_by_visible_text('ATLANTIC')
```

Comment: For the 1st piece of code, I'm getting this error: AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement

Comment: For the 2nd piece of code, I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: This is what YOU wrote. I have no idea how to locate that element

Comment: It's your code `mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("childContextDDL"))`

Comment: Yes, but I'm taking that id from html. Don't know why I'm getting that error

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the website?

Comment: Sorry, it's a confidential company website where you won't be able to log in. I talked to my colleague and he said that it's because the the display style is none. So I have to somehow make that visible? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: At the end in html you'll see 'style: display none'

Comment: I understand. It should be some user action that makes this element visible. Possibly tap on it, click on it, hover over it or some other element. maybe scroll to that element.

Comment: I've added the answer :)

Comment: Congrats! But you have to admit that we couldn't guess this from your initial question details

Comment: Haha it was still within the HTML code that I had posted but it was at the end. Anyway, it's fine, thanks for trying to help me out, really appreciate it!

Comment: I've asked 1 more question. If you have time, it will be helpful if you can look into it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784552/unable-to-click-on-an-ahref-link-using-python-selenium