# Unable to click on an ahref link using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

This is the html code:

```
<div id="dcf-page-export-buttons" class="no-print" style="display: block;">
                            <a id="dcf-saveaspdf" href="#" target="_blank" class="k-button">

                                Save as PDF
                            </a>
                            <a id="dcf-saveaspng" href="#" target="_blank" class="k-button">

                                Save as Image
                            </a>
                                                  <a id="dcf-printPdf" class="k-button" href="#">

                                Print
                            </a>
                        <a id="dcf-btnClose" class="k-button" href="#">

                            Close
                        </a>
                   </div>
```

I want to click on the Print href but it isn't being clicked. Here is my code:

```
exportLink = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Export")
exportLink.click()

print = driver.find_element_by_id("dcf-printPdf")
print.click()
```

Before finding element by id for print, I had clicked on Export href which opened a new tab and after opening of the new tab, I'm trying to click on print but getting an error. This is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Let me know if I'm going wrong somewhere or if there is a problem in the html.

---

**The first part of the question has been answered. This is the 2nd part:**

On clicking on this Print button:
[image]

This window gets opened. It's not a new tab per se, but just a new window. Within that window, I want to click on the Save button. Is there a way to go about doing that? This is how the view looks like:

[image]

And here is the html code.

```
<cr-button class="action-button" aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0">
    Save
  </cr-button>
```

Here is my code till now:

```
exportLink = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Export")
exportLink.click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('dcf-user-info').style.display = 'none';")

time.sleep(1)
print = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Print")
print.click()
```

This is the snip of the error log. I've added the snip because I'm unsure of the error.

[image]

Small continuation of the error:

[image]

Comment: Your error says `KeyboardInterrupt` --  for me that only happens if I CTRL-C in the terminal to end the process.  This happens every time you run your code?

Comment: Hey, I've found the correct answer which I've accepted.

Comment: Just to answer your question though, yes I did Ctrl + C and then got the Keyboard Interrupt message. It doesn't matter anyway because I got the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to new tab first then you can click on Print using that Id that you have been trying.

Switch to new windows like this :

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: Hey, I've edited my question to add the next part. Please can you look into. Thanks!

Comment: @ShridharK : Are you able to click on it ? If not what is the error now ? and why are are using this `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('dcf-user-info').style.display = 'none';")
` ?

Comment: I'm unable to click on it. That script is used by me to remove specific part of styling of the page, it's nothing to worry about. I'll add the error in my question.

Comment: Do you know how to switch to the window that I've shown? As I mentioned it's not a new tab as such but a window pop-up. If I'm able to switch to that, then maybe I'll be able to click on Save button

Comment: @ShridharK : It looks like Select class from selenium,  are you interacting with any drop down in your code using Select class ?

Comment: I'm interacting with a dropdown but that's in the 1st window, you won't find that code in the question code. Basically, what I'm doing is, I'm first selecting one territory from a dropdown, then I'm clicking on Export, which opens a new tab. After the new tab is opened, I click on Print which is part of this question and after clicking on print, as I mentioned, a new window gets opened which isn't a new browser tab per se. Now, within this new window, I want to click on 'Save'.

Comment: I believe you are able to click on `Print` right ? then you see a alert kind of window that says `Save` ? If you wanna click on save then that's something Selenium can't help in my experience. Nonetheless we can try either `AutoIT` if you are in windows environment or least we can try to switch to an alert using `Selenium` like this : `windows_alert = driver.switch_to.alert
windows_alert.accept()`

Comment: Yes, I'm able to click on Print. I tried pasting your windows_alert code at the bottom but nothing happened. Anyway, I'll quickly have lunch and will come back online, till then if you know of another way, please post it in your answer or as a comment. We can resume once I get back online. This looks tricky. Thanks!

Comment: Well that's a Windows pop up so you can not inspect HTML :(.  It is not part of web application that you have been testing. Either you need to use third party tool like `AutoIT` in windows environment or some other free source tool in different environment.  try submitting a new ticket for the exact Windows pop up `Save` button click.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.

Comment: I was able to solve it using this link: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/selenium+save+webpage+as+pdf+python

Comment: Hi, can you look at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834185/unable-to-select-the-linkedin-locations-dropdown-using-python-selenium

Comment: @ShridharK : looks like I am bit late :)

Comment: Not really :) Can you help me on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836200/trying-to-loop-through-profile-lists-using-selenium

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error, the element you trying to access is not interactable.
So, the problem is not with HTML.
I can't see the page you working on, but the problem can be that element you trying to access is out of the view.
Try this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

print = driver.find_element_by_id("dcf-printPdf")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(print).click(button).perform()
```

Comment: Hey, I've edited my question to add the next part. Please can you look into. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to solve it using this link: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/selenium+save+webpage+as+pdf+python

Comment: Hi, if you have time, can you look at my new questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834185/unable-to-select-the-linkedin-locations-dropdown-using-python-selenium