# Unable to select the LinkedIn 'locations' button using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation

I'm trying to click on the Locations dropdown in LinkedIn. You'll reach this section of the LinkedIn page by searching for something in the LinkedIn Search bar and then clicking on 'People'.

[image]

This is the HTML element:

```
<button aria-checked="false" role="button" aria-label="Locations filter. Clicking this button displays all Locations filter options." 
id="ember745" class="artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice ember-view search-reusables__filter-pill-button" aria-controls="artdeco-hoverable-artdeco-gen-54" aria-expanded="false" data-control-name="filter_top_bar_select" type="button">  
      Locations
<!---->      <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="caret-filled-down-icon" class="search-reusables__pill-button-caret-icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M8 11L3 6h10z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
    
</button>
```

These are the different codes that I've tried till now. Mind you, I can't select by id because LinkedIn is changing the ember number ID every few minutes.

```
locations = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice ember-view search-reusables__filter-pill-button"]')
locations = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Locations filter. Clicking this button displays all Locations filter options."]')
locations = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Locations filter. Clicking this button displays all Locations filter options.']/div[@class='artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice ember-view search-reusables__filter-pill-button' and text()='Locations']")
locations = browser.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice ember-view search-reusables__filter-pill-button"])[3]')
locations = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice ember-view search-reusables__filter-pill-button')))
```

I've spent a lot of time on this but haven't found a solution yet.

After clicking on Location, I also want to select United States and then click on Company Name and write a company name.

---

**Next part**:
This is the html for 'United States' location. I want to click on 'United States' and search for that filter.

```
<li class="search-reusables__collection-values-item">
        <input aria-label="Filter by United States" name="United States" id="geoUrn-103644278" class="search-reusables__select-input" data-control-name="filter_detail_select" type="checkbox" value="103644278">
        <label for="geoUrn-103644278" class="search-reusables__value-label">
          <p class="display-flex">
            <span class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
              United States
            </span>
          </p>
        </label>
<!---->      </li>
```

I tried this code but it didn't do anything:

```
unitedstates = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li//input[contains(@aria-label,"Filter by United States")]')))
unitedstates.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific button can be located with this XPath:

```
//span//button[contains(@aria-label,'Locations filter')]
```

So the element can be retrieved by

```
locations_btn = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span//button[contains(@aria-label,"Locations filter")]')))
```

The "United States" location can be selected by

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id,"locations-filter")]//li[@class="search-reusables__collection-values-item"]//span[contains(.,"United States")]'))).click()
```

Or if you want to click the checkbox you can use something like this:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id,"locations-filter")]//li[@class="search-reusables__collection-values-item" and .//span[contains(.,"United States")]]//input'))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks @Prophet. Can you write the entire statement of the code?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean writing the full code for the above statement like: browser.find_element_by_xpath...etc

Comment: is this what you are asking for? The updated answer

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me with one more thing. I want to select United States as a location. How should I select that? I'll paste the html for that in the question.

Comment: I've edited my question to include html for United States location.

Comment: I've added the code to select the United states location

Comment: Are there are any tips/tricks/sources that you can suggest me?

Comment: No, I just have some experience using XPath with Selenium :)

Comment: Nothing specific, just write code, gather experience, learn how XPath and CSS locators are built. It's just a syntax

Comment: Oops, had ticked it but forgot to upvote it. Thanks for reminding! By the way, didn't understand this part of the code: .//span[contains(.,"United States")]]//input'   ....why did you add input at the end?

Comment: `input` is the left side checkbox there. Or at least seems to be. So you can click on the `li` block element containing all that row or even better the `span` element actually containing that text. As a user. You can click on the text area to select it or on the checkbox on the left to it.

Comment: Can you help me on a new question that I've asked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836200/trying-to-loop-through-profile-lists-using-selenium

Comment: I had a question for this. Can I write the code without using the 'contains' word? For example, something like this? `locations_btn = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span//button[@aria-label,"Locations filter"]')))`