# Getting current designation using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the current designation of a LinkedIn profile list using Python Selenium. I want the part after the 'Current:' and the 'Summary:'.

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="linked-area flex-1 cursor-pointer">
  
        <p class="entity-result__summary entity-result__summary--2-lines t-12 t-black--light ">
          <!---->Current: Full Stack Software<span class="white-space-pre"> </span>
<strong><!---->Developer<!----></strong><span class="white-space-pre"> </span>at GE Healthcare<!---->
        </p>
      
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
currentDsgn = []
currentDesignations = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('linked-area flex-1')
    print(currentDesignations)

    for currentDesignation in currentDesignations:
        print(currentDesignation)
        currentDsgn.append(currentDesignation.text.strip())
```

But I got an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this xpath instead :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'linked-area')]/p[contains(@class, 'entity-result__summary')]
```

and use it like it below :

```
currentDesignations  = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'linked-area')]/p[contains(@class, 'entity-result__summary')]")
for currentDesignation in currentDesignations:
   print(currentDesignation.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Instead of starting with div class 'linked'area' what if we directly go to p class 'entity-result__summary'?

Comment: Yes @ShridharK we can do that. Just make sure that in element structure (When you press F12) and when you use the mentioned xpath, your desired elements should be highlighted

Comment: And can we write the code without using the 'contains' keyword? Something like: `@class = 'linked-area'` or `@class = 'entity-result-summary'`?

Comment: No we cannot. If we write `@class = 'linked-area` Selenium will look for exact match, we wanted to pass sub part of the class hence we used `contains`

Comment: This makes sense