# select country with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[Click here for see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JxZV.png)I'm learning python, but I don't know how to select this part, anyone help me?

I tried to select the cell with xpath and put the country but I don't know how to select it to assign the value

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']")
test.send_keys('United States')
test.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to select the list item.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']"))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('United States')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('3')
```

Link to original answer]([How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)).

Comment: I tried this way but it doesn't work, could you look at the image please

Comment: All the options to select are as follows:  <li role="option" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0" class="up-menu-item">

Comment: What you are clicking on in the image is IFRAME. It is not the element you want. Check the <ul class="up-menu-list up-menu-fullscreen"> that is what actually holds the element <li>. I think you are providing the XPATH to the IFRAME instead of the ul @BrianDaniel

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
# Assuming this this the correct xpath to the search bar
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']") 
test.click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'United States') and @class='up-menu-item']").click()
```