# How to pick the right options in a dropdown menu with Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Here's the dropdown menu :

[image: dropdown]

and

[image: dropdown2]

It's on `Range` by default and I would like my script to move it to `Custom`

I tried several ways, but all stay on the scrolldown menu (the 2nd picture) and didn't pick `Custom`

Here's my code so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://www.mergermarket.com/homepage'
driver.get(url)
deals = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[4]/a')
urldeals = deals.get_attribute("href")
driver.get(urldeals)

body_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCriteriaSummary"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')

custom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCriteriaSummary"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')
custom.click()
custom.send_keys('Custom') 
custom.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

I got this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

EDIT2 :
I froze the brower's inspector to visualise the html of the dropdown and there is not `Select`

[image: dropdown]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python)

Comment: It could be but maybe I did it wrong ? I got this error :  `selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>`

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Nasty, select the dropdown in the console/F12 mode. In the console type: $0.Click()   the dropdown should appear. Now try to navigate to whatever it is under elements to get the real html. Maybe some hidden elements at the button of the page appear?

Comment: F12 mode ? You mean inspect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete rewrite, it turns out this is NOT a normal Select where we can use the Selenium Select class.
Different approach, try to get the element which IS clickable. Your xPath is very long and I can't see which element is targets. Could you try these options?
Currently you send a sendKeys to a div, which Selenium finds odd as it is not a textfield (it should be a Select, but we need to live with that)

```
custom.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id=""react-select-12-option-0"]').click()
# or this one
custom.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "Custom")]')
```

Comment: I got this error : `selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>`

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Edited my answer, look for the select & dig deeper

Comment: I edited my post, I dig deeper like you said and didn't found select

Comment: Rewrote my answer

Comment: Thanks :) help a lot !