# I want to write xpath for the dropdown list and select all sesason's in python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I have tried this to navigate from the season's drop down.

```
try:
    add = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//ul[@class='dropdown dropdown__filter']/li[@class='pv-h'])
except:
    print("Error on dropdown")

try:
    Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(add).perform()
    data=driver.find_element_by_by_xpath(/ul[@class='dropdown dropdown__filter']/li[@class='pv-h'])
    time.sleep(2)
```

Error 1: add = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class='dropdown dropdown__filter']/li[@class='pv-h']')

Error 2: Deprecation error: try find_elements_by()

Comment: Please go through the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because selenium does not allow to find elements by compound classes, ie. class attribute that has more than one value.

Try this:

```
try:
    add = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//ul[contains(@class='dropdown__filter')]/li[@class='pv-h'])
except:
    print("Error on dropdown")
```