# Selenium python - Selecting drop down option for automated web data entry

Tags: python, selenium, data-entry

I'm quite new to selenium python and have been attempting to write a script to automate data entry into a website using data from an excel file (essentially creating user accounts). All is working well however I am stuck on trying to select an option from a drop-menu that is required on the website (unable to link as contains sensitive information). The drop-down selection for 'Site' contains examples such as 'ABC Hospital', and for 'Role' such as 'Applicant' (these will be consistent for all the accounts created, so won't need to be read from the excel document).

As far as I can tell, the id for the element is different each time you enter the page, and the list isn't stored as a list element, so I have been unsuccessful at using the Xpath method of identifying the elements as with the other fields, so I am stumped on how to progress with being able to select the dropdown option for both 'Site' and 'Role' in the screenshot link provided.
[Link to screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLcRZ.png)

If there's any more information you need to help with my query, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: may this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python

Comment: Please share HTML code, code trials, error stack trace if any.