# How to select drop-down list in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

need select this <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="480">г. Когалым</div>

```
<div class="selectize-control selectize single"><div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options"><input type="select-one" autocomplete="new-password" autofill="no" tabindex="" id="city-selectized" style="width: 4px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;"></div><div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 480px; top: 40px; left: 0px;"><div class="selectize-dropdown-content"><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="294">г. Белоярский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="480">г. Когалым</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="483">г. Лангепас</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="316">г. Лянтор</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="474">г. Мегион</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="485">г. Нефтеюганск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="475">г. Нижневартовск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="476">г. Нягань</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="478">г. Покачи</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="471">г. Пыть-Ях</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="481">г. Радужный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="461">г. Советский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="482">г. Сургут</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="484">г. Урай</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="477">г. Ханты-Мансийск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="472">г. Югорск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="339">д. Анеева</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="366">д. Белогорье</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="452">д. Большой Ларьяк</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="460">д. Вампугол</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="458">д. Вата</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="319">д. Верхне-Мысовая</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="344">д. Верхненильдина</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="413">д. Верхние Нарыкары</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="335">д. Деминская</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="380">д. Долгое Плесо</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="426">д. Ильичевка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="439">д. Кама</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="325">д. Каюкова</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="345">д. Кимкьясуй</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="362">д. Лугофилинская</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="322">д. Лямина</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="350">д. Нерохи</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="412">д. Нижние Нарыкары</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="427">д. Никулкина</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="296">д. Нумто</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="370">д. Нялина</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="446">д. Пасол</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="299">д. Пашторы</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="336">д. Пугоры</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="320">д. Русскинская</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="317">д. Сайгатина</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="346">д. Сартынья</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="369">д. Согом</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="447">д. Соснина</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="453">д. Сосновый бор</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="431">д. Сотник</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="428">д. Старый Катыш</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="327">д. Тайлакова</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="326">д. Таурова</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="456">д. Усть-Колекъеган</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="351">д. Усть-Манья</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="435">д. Ушья</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="348">д. Хулимсунт</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="347">д. Хурумпауль</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="411">д. Чемаши</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="364">д. Чембакчина</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="454">д. Чехломей</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="337">д. Шайтанка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="377">д. Шапша</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="436">д. Шугур</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="342">д. Щекурья</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="297">д. Юильск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="429">д. Юмас</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="368">д. Ягурьях</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="378">д. Ярки</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="343">д. Ясунт</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="443">п. Аган</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="463">п. Алябьевский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="302">п. АСС ГПЗ</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="308">п. Банный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="361">п. Бобровский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="398">п. Большие Леуши</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="330">п. Ванзетур</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="445">п. Ваховск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="292">п. Верхнеказымский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="354">п. Выкатной</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="305">п. Высокий Мыс</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="360">п. Горноправдинск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="401">п. Горнореченск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="314">п. Горный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="415">п. Дальний</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="442">п. Зайцева Речка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="397">п. Заречный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="383">п. Каркатеевы</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="396">п. Карымкары</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="357">п. Кедровый</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="352">п. Кирпичный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="393">п. Комсомольский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="403">п. Кормужиханка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="359">п. Красноленинский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="386">п. Куть-Ях</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="420">п. Лиственичный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="355">п. Луговской</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="291">п. Лыхма</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="313">п. Малоюганский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="421">п. Мулымья</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="423">п. Назарово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="310">п. Нижнесортымский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="479">п. Ортьягун</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="303">п. Песчаный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="425">п. Половинка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="329">п. Приполярный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="353">п. Пырьях</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="385">п. Салым</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="332">п. Светлый</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="388">п. Сентябрьский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="392">п. Сергино</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="356">п. Сибирский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="382">п. Сивыс-Ях</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="387">п. Сингапай</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="315">п. Солнечный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="293">п. Сорум</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="290">п. Сосновка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="331">п. Сосьва</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="414">п. Супра</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="470">п. Тимкапауль</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="307">п. Тром-Аган</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="311">п. Ульт-Ягун</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="402">п. Унъюган</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="358">п. Урманный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="333">п. Устрем</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="381">п. Усть-Юган</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="466">п. Юбилейный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="304">п. Юган ЛЗУ</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="391">п. Юганская Обь</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="416">п. Ягодный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="469">пгт. Агириш</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="395">пгт. Андра</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="306">пгт. Барсово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="312">пгт. Белый Яр</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="328">пгт. Березово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="473">пгт. Высокий</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="462">пгт. Зеленоборск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="334">пгт. Игрим</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="444">пгт. Излучинск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="464">пгт. Коммунистический</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="417">пгт. Кондинское</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="418">пгт. Куминский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="419">пгт. Луговой</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="467">пгт. Малиновский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="422">пгт. Междуреченский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="424">пгт. Мортка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="441">пгт. Новоаганск</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="399">пгт. Октябрьское</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="468">пгт. Пионерский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="384">пгт. Пойковский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="400">пгт. Приобье</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="465">пгт. Таежный</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="394">пгт. Талинка</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="309">пгт. Федоровский</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="440">с. Алтай</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="375">с. Батово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="438">с. Болчары</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="448">с. Большетархово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="406">с. Большой Атлым</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="404">с. Большой Камень</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="459">с. Былино</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="300">с. Ванзеват</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="449">с. Варьеган</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="365">с. Елизарово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="379">с. Зенково</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="295">с. Казым</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="408">с. Каменное</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="437">с. Карым</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="451">с. Корлики</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="372">с. Кышик</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="450">с. Ларьяк</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="390">с. Лемпино</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="432">с. Леуши</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="318">с. Локосово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="341">с. Ломбовож</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="405">с. Малый Атлым</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="349">с. Няксимволь</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="371">с. Нялинское</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="455">с. Охтеурье</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="409">с. Пальяново</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="410">с. Перегребное</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="457">с. Покур</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="298">с. Полноват</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="374">с. Реполово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="340">с. Саранпауль</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="373">с. Селиярово</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="321">с. Сытомино</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="338">с. Теги</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="367">с. Троица</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="301">с. Тугияны</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="323">с. Тундрино</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="376">с. Тюли</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="324">с. Угут</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="363">с. Цингалы</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="433">с. Чантырья</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="389">с. Чеускино</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="434">с. Шаим</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="407">с. Шеркалы</div><div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="430">с. Ямки</div></div></div></div>
```

```
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('city-selectized'))
dropdown.select_by_index(481)
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python

Comment: That is not a select tag you need to click on the tag and then the preceeding element.