# Selenium: Dropdown value selection from list

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python and Selenium to add certain information to a form.

In this case, I need to insert the city of residence, selecting it from an auto-complete drop-down menu.

Altough the list is dynamic and may change depending on other values, to illustrate, I would like to select "Roma".

> How can I effectively find and select a value from a list that is
> dynamically changing, using Selenium?

I tried with the methodology explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python), but the following error is reported:

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>
```

[image: After text addition]

Snippets of the html code from the page are the following:

```
<input autocomplete="off" placeholder=" " id="dx_dx-e8acb639-2bdd-7dda-710a-2d81f408dc73_ComuneNascitaPk" class="dx-texteditor-input" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="true">
```

From the expanded list:

```
<div class="dx-scrollview-content" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);"><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Affile</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Agosta</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Albano Laziale</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Allumiere</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Anguillara Sabazia</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Anticoli Corrado</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Anzio</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Arcinazzo Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Ardea</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Ariccia</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Arsoli</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Artena</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Bellegra</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Bracciano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Camerata Nuova</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Campagnano di Roma</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Canale Monterano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Canterano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Capena</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Capranica Prenestina</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Carpineto Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Casape</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Castel Gandolfo</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Castel Madama</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Castel San Pietro Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Castelnuovo di Porto</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Cave</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Cerreto Laziale</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Cervara di Roma</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Cerveteri</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Ciampino</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Ciciliano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Cineto Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Civitavecchia</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Civitella San Paolo</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Colleferro</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Colonna</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Fiano Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Filacciano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Fiumicino</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Fonte Nuova</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Formello</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Frascati</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Gallicano nel Lazio</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Gavignano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Genazzano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Genzano di Roma</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Gerano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Gorga</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Grottaferrata</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Guidonia Montecelio</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Jenne</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Labico</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Ladispoli</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Lanuvio</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Lariano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Licenza</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Magliano Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Mandela</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Manziana</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Marano Equo</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Marcellina</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Marino</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Mazzano Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Mentana</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Monte Compatri</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Monte Porzio Catone</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Monteflavio</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Montelanico</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Montelibretti</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Monterotondo</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Montorio Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Moricone</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Morlupo</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Nazzano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Nemi</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Nerola</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Nettuno</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Olevano Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Palestrina</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Palombara Sabina</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Percile</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Pisoniano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Poli</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Pomezia</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Ponzano Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Riano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Rignano Flaminio</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Riofreddo</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Rocca Canterano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Rocca di Cave</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Rocca di Papa</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Rocca Priora</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Rocca Santo Stefano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Roccagiovine</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Roiate</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Roma</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Roviano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Sacrofano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Sambuci</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">San Cesareo</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">San Gregorio da Sassola</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">San Polo dei Cavalieri</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">San Vito Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Santa Marinella</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Sant'Angelo Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Sant'Oreste</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Saracinesco</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Segni</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Subiaco</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Tivoli</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Tolfa</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Torrita Tiberina</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Trevignano Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Vallepietra</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Vallinfreda</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Valmontone</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Velletri</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Vicovaro</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Vivaro Romano</div></div><div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false"><div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">Zagarolo</div></div></div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share url of the page

Comment: It unfortunately requires user auth with private credentials; hope you'll understand.

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You really can't use `Select` class since you're trying to handle `div` node not `select` node...
You can use this approach to select reqired value

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Add code for clicking on input field to expand drop-down menu
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='option' and .='Roma']"))).click()
```

Comment: It works! thanks; Since there are multiple of those dropdowns, how can you select each one and fill it as illustrated? By priorly clicking on them seems to be working ...

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli You should click on respective input fields. Selecting required option I guess should be the same for each menu - just pass value to predicate `[@role='option' and .='Roma']` instead of `'Roma'`. But in case of issues it's better to provide HTML of each drop-down menu...