# Error by getting selected option using Selenium Web Driver with Python

Tags: python, selenium

In order to output my already selected option I coded:

```
Select(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'path_to_select/select/option'))
selected_option = select.first_selected_option
print(selected_option)
```

Error Message:

> raise UnexpectedTagNameException(
> selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on  elements, not on

Comment: Post your full code (or at least a minimal reproducible example), as well as the url of the page in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are selecting a list of elements. So you can use `driver.find_element()` instead of driver.find_elements() to select a single element.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'path_to_select/select/option'))
selected_option = select.first_selected_option
print(selected_option)
```

Comment: it shows: **selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <option>**

Comment: You can follow answers from here how to select dropdown correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_elements` returns list of `WebElements`

should be `driver.find_element`. Note the `s` in `find_element`