# Trigger JavaScript event if div innerText change

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, innertext

I want to make an alert when a div's innerText changes:

```
myDiv.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (myDiv.innerText != "some text")
        alert('innerText has changed.');
},false);
```

Does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Event : Detect changes to the html/text of a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change

Comment: not possible in pure JS?

Comment: Way easier option to do this in JQuery.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div

Comment: thank you all, but the topic title is: "Javascript".

Comment: This `div`, is it a content editable, or just a regular `div`?

Comment: it is regular div.. I want to detect when its text is changed by a third function.. so the event listener  detect any change..

Comment: [Mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) might help you to find a solution. You can also search for it at SO, there's lot of questions about mutation events.

Comment: in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrtAK/) an interval is used as third function that changes the text

Comment: Why don't you store the innerText in a variable and then test to see if it's different than the variable? Or is this in a textField and you want to check AS they type.

Comment: The original text is changed by a function that I don't know, so I need to a listener that detect whatever change of the text

Comment: I found a solution! Many Thanks to you All! :) see update

Comment: Thanks for wanting to make your solution available to readers. However, the question is not the best place for this - we welcome self-answers here, so if you find the answer before someone else, add a answer and mark it as correct by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 15):

`myDiv.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", function (event) { // ... add your code he }, false);`

use DOMCharacterDataModified to detect innerText change event

Comment: [As per W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#legacy-mutationevent-events:~:text=Thus%2C%20this%20specification%20describes%20mutation%20events%20for%20reference%20and%20completeness%20of%20legacy%20behavior%2C%20but%20deprecates%20the%20use%20of%20the%20MutationEvent%20interface.), Mutation Events have been deprecated in favor of [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 6):

*Posted on behalf of the OP*.

I found a solution:

```
// THIRD FUNCTION (changes the text)
var i = 0;
function thirdFUN(){
    i++;
    var popo = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    popo.innerText = i;
}
setInterval(thirdFUN, 500);

//---------------------------------------------------------------

// JQUERY
/*var popo = $('#myDiv');
$('#myDiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    if (popo.html() == "10")
    console.log('changed');
});
*/

//---------------------------------------------------------------

// PURE JS
window.onload = function(){

var popo = document.querySelector('#myDiv');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        console.log(mutation.type); // <- It always detects changes
        if (popo.innerHTML == "10"){
            alert('hello');
        }
    });    
});

var config = {characterData: true, subtree: true};
observer.observe(popo, config);
//observer.disconnect();

}
```

This is [also a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrtAK/1/).

Comment: doesn't seem to work any more

Comment: @AkashJain: you may need to post a new question. If you do so, show what code you have presently and where you think it is not working specifically.

Comment: actually it the JS fiddle that is provided in the link, its not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event isn't specified to fire at any point the text changes. It fires only when the textarea loses focus (the user clicks away or tabs away). So your event will only fire when this happens.

Aside from continually checking the value of the textarea with an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), there is no elegant way to do this (to my knowledge).

Note in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75m53/) that the `change` event only fires after the textarea has lost focus.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218599/726766) for more info...

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on the top answer since not enough reputation, but according to MDN, Mutation Events (so including DOMCharacterDataModified) were deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Luckily, you can get the same thing with [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) now.

Comment: Could you please share example code which utilizes Mutation Observers?

Answer (score -3):

try

`document.addEventListener("change", function()` ......