# listener for div tag change

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using a third part library to scan QR code. After scan is complete `<div id="qr-code-status"></div>` content changes. During the scan process div tag's innerText says "QR code scanning". Once scan complete innerText changes to "QR code scan complete". I would like catch when it changes to "QR code scan complete" so I can take user to the next page.

After QR code scan, if I type `document.getElementByID("qr-code-status").innerText` in browser console, I get "QR code scan complete". Need to find out the way to catch it in the code

Doing something like this is not working:

```
componentDidUpdate {
  if(document.getElementByID("qr-code-status").innerText === "QR code scan complete") {
     this.nextPage();
  }
}
```

What would be the best implementation?

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/24388822/7949123

Comment: use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: You could just use `useEffect()` hook. Assign a state to the QR code and add it to the dependency array of the hook. When the state changes, move to the next page.

Comment: _what_ changes the text? Because if it's your code, you already know where to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
status = document.getElementById("qr-code-status");
this.observer = new MutationObserver(() => {this.observer.disconnect(); this.nextPage();});
this.observer.observe(status, { characterData: true });
```

This will automatically disconnect once something changes. Then it will call `this.nextPage`.