# Update the observable when input value is changed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to update an observable when the `<input>` value is changed, but programatically, i.e. by Javascript?

Here is a jsfiddle of this use case that I am not able to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/qYXdJ/

As you see when the "Update input value by Javascript" link is clicked the observable is obviously not updated, since it is not reflected in the `<span>`

Comment: This might not help you, but under the hood, updates are detected by `change` events. Programatically changing the value of an input field does not seem to fire a `change` event: http://jsfiddle.net/qYXdJ/3/

Comment: I am a little confused which is probably due to my lack of ko knowledge, but when I click "Update input value by Javascript" after inputting some text, the text appears next to the "The input value is: :", so the <span> is updated. What am I missing?

Comment: You should be seeing "The input value is: New Value" instead

Comment: tomor - Can you explain the need to change the input's value and not the observables value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you absolutely **can't** modify the observable directly (which is the best way), you can trigger the "onchange" event (which Knockout uses internally). With jQuery, it's a simple matter:

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
    $('#input2').val('New Value').trigger('change');
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery for whatever reason, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/trigger-onchange-event-manually).

Comment: In the end I ended up doing something like this. Basically, the value is set with Javascript and then I manually trigger the 'change' event. Seems to be working fine so far! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the hint about using `change()` :-)

Answer (score 4):

As cyanfish pointed out the correct way is to update the observable.

If the problem is your code doesn't have access to the observable, for example you're writing a bookmarklet to automatically fill out a form, then you can gain access to the observable like this:

```
function setValue(input, value) {
  var bindingsString = input.getAttribute('data-bind');
  if (bindingsString) {
    var bindings = ko.bindingProvider.instance.parseBindingsString(bindingsString, ko.contextFor(input), input);
    if (bindings.value) {
      bindings.value(value);
    } else if (bindings.checked) {
      bindings.checked(value);
    } else {
      input.value = value;
    }
  } else {
    input.value = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the viewModel 'name' property instead of input field value, because it's observable, and any changes on the property will be reflected to all binded html elements.

```
var viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable()
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    document.getElementById('update').onclick = function(){
        viewModel.name('New Value');
        //document.getElementById('input2').value = 'New Value';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to change the input field explicitly, rather than writing on the observable.

Comment: Your input field is not observable.