# Knockout validation - reset date fields

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I am trying to reset the date values (which are invalid for eg: partially filled dates like 12/...) on form submit (while saving as a draft form). I have done the following:

```
                $(".datepicker").each(function(){
                    if(parseDate($(this).val())==null)
                        {
                            $(this).val('');
                        }
                });
```

where the function is:

```
               function parseDate(str){
                    var t = str.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/);
                    if(t!==null){
                      var d=+t[1], m=+t[2], y=+t[3];
                      var date = new Date(y,m-1,d);
                      if(date.getFullYear()===y && date.getMonth()===m-1){
                        return date;   
                      }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
```

Even if the text field is getting updated, it is not updating the value of the observable which is bound to the textbox. I tried valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' as well but, I would imagine, that event will not get fired while updating the textbox via jquery.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.... I have changed

$(this).val('');
to
$(this).val('').trigger('change');

as mentioned in

[Update the observable when input value is changed by Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324084/update-the-observable-when-input-value-is-changed-by-javascript)

Comment: I don't think this is what you want to do...  The purpose of using an observable is to be able to set it client side ie. if you have a dateObservable and something is changed just set dateObservable('');