# How to run jquery function on update when field is updated programatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a function `loadcomputers()` that otomatically update a select list with `id=computer`
`loadcomputers()` gets the filter form the input field with `id="rating"`
input field with `id="rating"` is automatically filled out by another function `rate(item)`
Problem is when input field with id="rating" is automatically filled out, the function loadcomputers() dosn't load but if I type manually it works

```
 <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input class="ccheckbx" type="checkbox" name="application[]" value="1" onClick="rate(this);"  />Office              
      </li>
      <li>
        <input class="ccheckbx" type="checkbox" name="application[]" value="2" onClick="rate(this);"  />Game 
      </li>     
    </ul>

      <input type="text" id="rating" oncchange="loadcomputers()"/>
      <select name="computer" id="computer"></select>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------

  var total = 0;

function rate(item){
    if(item.checked){
       total+= parseInt(item.value);
    }else{
       total-= parseInt(item.value);
    }
    //alert(total);
    document.getElementById('rating').value = total + "";
}
-------------------------------------------

function loadcomputers() {
    $val = $('#rating').val();
    $.post('http://exemple1.com/action/subs/pcdrop2.php', {
    rating: $val
    }, function (data) {
    $('#computer').html(data);
});
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667105/onchange-event-not-working-when-change-automated

Comment: Thank you but not ecxacly the same.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to trigger the event yourself by using

```
$('#rating').trigger('change');
```

in `loadComputers()`

*btw: there is a typo, it's supposed to be `onchange`, you have `oncchange`*

Comment: Thank you I have tried this but it is not working. `function loadcomputers() {
    $val = $('#rating').val();
    $.post('http://onlinepcdoc.com/action/subs/pcdrop2.php', {
        rating: $val
    }, function (data) {
        $('#computer').html(data);
        $('#rating').trigger('change');
    });
}`

Comment: I added `$('#rating').trigger('change');` on rate(item) instate and it worked. Thank you.